# How to break a long equation?

Tags: equations, line-breaking

I have an equation long enough to occupy two lines.
I want to break it to improve readability. How can I break it?

```
\begin{equation}
F = \{F_{x} \in  F_{c} : (|S| > |C|) \cap 
(minPixels  < |S| < maxPixels) \cap 
(|S_{connected}| > |S| - \epsilon)
  \}
\end{equation}
```

I want to break it in 3 lines after `\cap`. But `\\` or `\n` didn't work.

Comment: Relevant: [automatic line breaking](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/how-can-i-split-an-equation-over-two-lines) for long equations using the `breqn` package.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this:
http://www.gocomics.com/strangebrew/2016/04/15

Comment: You may also be interested in reading Leslie Lamport's ["How to write a long formula"](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01211870) and ["How to write a 21st century proof"](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11784-012-0071-6) (there's also a talk [here](http://www.heidelberg-laureate-forum.org/blog/video/lecture-tuesday-september-23-2014-leslie-lamport/)).

Answer (score 232, accepted):

Use `split` environment provided by `amsmath` package.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
F = \{F_{x} \in  F_{c} &: (|S| > |C|) \\
 &\quad \cap (\text{minPixels}  < |S| < \text{maxPixels}) \\
 &\quad \cap (|S_{\text{conected}}| > |S| - \epsilon) \}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: And it would look even nicer with a `\mathrm{minPixels}` and `\mathrm{maxPixels}` and `\mathrm{connected}`.

Comment: @Bruno: I agree. I edited the answer to use `\text`.

Comment: Be aware that `\text` inherits formatting from the surrounding text (which might be italic in a theorem environment).

Comment: When using `\right(` and `\left)` or similar, one should be careful. The `\left.` and `\right.` should be used in order to avoid splitting of brackets pairs. For example a line should have the form `\left( \ldots \right. \\` when it involves this kind of brackets.

Comment: I get an error when using \left\{ and \right\} instead of \{ and \}.

Comment: Can `split` be used with displaymath (that is between $$ $$) instead of using it with `equation`? I tried and it always gives me an error of the form `missing } inserted`, even if I don't write anything between `begin` and `end`, that is even just `$$ \begin{split} \end{split} $$` does not work.

Comment: Why is the syntax for this so unnecessarily complicated?

Answer (score 59):

The `aligned` environment from `amsmath` is also a good option:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
F ={} & \{F_{x} \in  F_{c} : (|S| > |C|) \\
      & \cap (\mathrm{minPixels}  < |S| < \mathrm{maxPixels}) \\
      & \cap (|S_{\mathrm{conected}}| > |S| - \epsilon)\}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: What does the empty `{}` do?

Comment: @TylerCrompton - The empty `{}` works as a math atom to keep the correct spacing around the `=` symbol, because `=` is a binary operator just like the `+` and the `-` symbols. When you type `$-5$` and `$x-5$`, the first `-` is a unary operator and is close to the `5`, but the second `-` is a binary operator with larger and equal distances from both `x` and `5`--the same logic holds here.

Answer (score 43):

For simple multi-line equations without alignment, use the `multline` environment:

```
\begin{multline}
F = \{F_{x} \in  F_{c} : (|S| > |C|) \cap 
(minPixels  < |S| < maxPixels) \\ \cap 
(|S_{conected}| > |S| - \epsilon)
  \}
\end{multline}
```

Comment: But you would want alignment here, wouldn't you?

Comment: Sometimes you want Latex to take care of alignment for you, this environment works nicely in this case.

Answer (score 19):

The [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/mathtools.html) package provides the `multlined` environment.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}
F = \{F_{x} \in  F_{c} : (|S| > |C|) \\
\shoveleft[1cm]{\cap (\mathrm{minPixels}  < |S| < \mathrm{maxPixels})} \\
\cap (|S_{\mathrm{connected}}| > |S| - \epsilon) \}
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: I checked the latest version of the `mathtools` package (1.17) and it has no such environment.  Perhaps it's been removed since you posted your answer.

Comment: @Psychonaut It does indeed have that environment, and has had that all along. Just make sure you are typing `multlined` (`mult` without `i`, i.e. _not_ `multilined`).

Answer (score -6):

```
\begin{eqnarray}
  F = \{F_{x} \in  F_{c} : (|S| > |C|) \cap \nonumber \\
  (minPixels  < |S| < maxPixels) \cap \nonumber \\
  (|S_{conected}| > |S| - \epsilon)
  \\}
\end{eqnarray}
```

Comment: Don't use `{eqnarray}`: [eqnarray vs align](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align)

Comment: Isn't using `eqnarray` a bit pointless if no alignment ponts are employed? (The fact `eqnarray` is badly deprecated is another strike against it.)

Comment: @Mico A point would be that it is the only way the LaTeX kernel provides; the other display math environments do not support several equation lines. But, of course, a package like `amsmath` is the preferred way.