# How do I add a line break in display math mode?

Tags: math-mode

For instance, how do I add a break after the first line in

```
\[
    a + b = c // what should I add here?
    a = c - b
\]
```

Answer (score 139, accepted):

The `\[...\]` is used to typeset a single equation, not multiple equations.

You need to use an environment that allows for multiple equations. One way is to use `gather`, but I normally use `align`, both from the `amsmath` package:

[image]

### Notes:

- With display math environments if you leave blank lines in between you get additional vertical spacing and the possibility of a page break between a paragraph and following display.
- If you don't want the equations numbered use the starred versions of the environments: `gather*` and `align*`.
- A really good reference is Herbert Voss's  [comprehensive review of mathematics in (La)TeX](https://ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
    a + b = c \\ 
    a = c - b
\end{gather}
%
With the align environment you can align equations:
%
\begin{align}
    a + b &= c \\        
        a &= c - b
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried `align`, it shows everything on the same line. My code: http://pastebin.com/FwwSmiCp Result: [image description](http://i.stack.imgur.com/00X6X.png)

Comment: @TomášZato: You need a double back slash to indicate a new line, not a single backslash. Next time, for faster response, just post a new question.  You won't be the last person to make such a mistake  -- even if it gets closed, the comments will still contain a fix, so a question like that might help someone else in the future. I see that there is a typo in my answer, so fixing that now...

Comment: As of January 9th, your link to Herbert Voss's eview of LaTeX math is [dead](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/math/voss/mathmode/).

Comment: with align, I'm getting equation numbers next to each line. I preferred this answer to a similar question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8942/14277

Comment: @craq: Glad you were able to locate a solution for your issue. However, this question is about adding a line break _between_ equations, not about splitting a _single_ equation across multiple lines.

Answer (score 7):

In case `gather` is not an option, for example, an imported command where everything is in math mode, consider make them a single-columned matrix without showing the symbol, then you can use `\\`.

Code:

```latex
\[
\begin{array}{c}
a + b = c \\  % just use \\
a = c - b
\end{array}
\]
```

Comment: This solution works, but it might be important to keep in mind that in an ``array`` environment, the content is (by default) in ``\textstyle`` rather than in ``\displaystyle``. Hence, for example, a fraction written with ``\frac{}{}`` will be smaller than in an usual display math environment, and the limits of a sum or of an integral will be displayed differently. But one could simply add a ``\displaystyle`` command in cells where this behavior should be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use two modes.

```
\[
    a + b = c
\]
\[
    a = c - b
\]
```

Comment: There will be too much space between the two lines, and also the possibility of a page break.  Not a good choice.