# Is it possible to get a new line in \{text bla bla text\}?

Tags: math-mode

Is it possible to get a new line inside of {text bla bla text} in LaTeX, specifically in mathmode?

I want to be able to write something like this:

[image]

Comment: The answer here is "yes." Can you supply some more context? And a minimal working example?

Comment: Take a look at all of the answers here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46189/how-do-i-add-a-line-break-in-display-math-mode

Comment: @Werner See my edit of the post.

Comment: @Ben123: So you're looking for something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1lSF.png)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=huge]
\biggl\{
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  Ideals of \\ $\mathbb{K}[\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n]$
  \end{tabular}
\biggr\}
\arrow[r,shift left=1ex,"Z"]
&
\biggl\{
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  Subsets of $\mathbb{A}^n$
  \end{tabular}
\biggr\}
\arrow[l,shift left=1ex,"I"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You *really* want *I* underneath the arrow, in order to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \left\{
    \begin{matrix}
      \text{Ideals of} \\
      \mathbb{K}\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\} \\
    \end{matrix}
  \right\}
  \begin{matrix}
    \xrightarrow{\mskip50mu \smash{Z} \mskip50mu} \\
    \xleftarrow{\mskip50mu \smash{I} \mskip50mu} \\
  \end{matrix}
  \left\{
    \begin{matrix}
      \text{subsets of } \mathbb{A}^n \\
      \\
    \end{matrix}
  \right\}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Or like this ...

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[\Bigg\{\begin{array}{c}
\text{Ideals of}\\
\mathbb{K}[\alpha_{1},\dots,\alpha_{n}]
\end{array}\Bigg\} 
\xleftrightharpoons[~~~~I~~~~]{Z}
\Bigg\{ \begin{array}{c}
\text{subsets of}\ \mathbb{A}^{n}
\end{array}
\Bigg\}\]
\end{document}
```