# Formatting LaTeX-dump from Mathematica equations for A4-paper without manual adjusting?

Tags: formatting, wolfram-mathematica

*I asked this question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13010/dump-many-equations-from-mathematica-to-latex-without-manual-adjusting) in Mathematica.SE but they encouraged to ask also on this site.*

[image]

How can make this writing process easier from Mathematica to LaTeX? Please, note that I have a lot of variables and I want to make them visible to the reader, I am not much interested how but not over the page so have to break the equations and perhaps other formatting, possible to get it directly from Mathematica?

**Mathematica Code**

```
AA = -a*g/(A*(2*g*h)^(1/2));
aa = (F1 + F2)^2/(2*a^2*g);
BB = 2/A;
Du = F1 + F2 - 1.2;
Dx = h - aa;
Px = AA*Dx - BB*Du // Simplify;

{AA, aa, BB, Du, Dx, Px} // TeXForm (*perhaps wrong way here? I want to show the above lines fast and accessible to the reader*)
```

**Out**

```
\left\{-\frac{a g}{\sqrt{2} A \sqrt{g h}},\frac{(\text{F1}+\text{F2})^2}{2 a^2
   g},\frac{2}{A},\text{F1}+\text{F2}-1.2,h-\frac{(\text{F1}+\text{F2})^2}{2 a^2 g},-\frac{\frac{\sqrt{2} a g
   \left(h-\frac{(\text{F1}+\text{F2})^2}{2 a^2 g}\right)}{\sqrt{g h}}+4. (\text{F1}+\text{F2}-1.2)}{2 A}\right\}
```

**My by-hand edited thing, time-consuming (too long, have to break it somehow)**

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
{A',a',B',\Delta u, \Delta x, \partial x} := \left\{
-\frac{a g}{\sqrt{2} A \sqrt{g h}}, \\
\frac{(\text{F1}+\text{F2})^2}{2 a^2 g}, \\
\frac{2}{A}, \\
\text{F1}+\text{F2}-1.2, \\
h-\frac{(\text{F1}+\text{F2})^2}{2 a^2 g}, \\
-\frac{\frac{\sqrt{2} a g \left(h-\frac{(\text{F1}+\text{F2})^2}{2 a^2 g}\right)}{\sqrt{g h}}+4. (\text{F1}+\text{F2}-1.2)}{2 A} \\
\right.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

**Perhaps related**

1. [How to break a long equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8936/how-to-break-long-equation)

Comment: Related: [How to make \left, \right pairs of delimiter work over multiple lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21290) (this is why your last code won't compile.) | I'm no expert on Mathematica, but why don't you just use `gather` or `align` and typeset a variable per line (as in your input)?

Answer (score 1):

This is a (typographically) response to [OP's own answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77630/16595).
(Sorry, still no Mathematica-automation answer. This seems to be a job for either Mathematica itself or a [Preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor).)

**Notes:**

- Don't use blank lines to pad your math environment from the text. This introduces a new paragraph.
- Don't use a space before a `-`. To LaTeX, these are two separate words (`matrix` and `-case`) and breaks hyphenation.
- I removed two unnecassary parenthesis from the last equation.
- The `align` environment produces separate equation numbers, not only one for four/five lines.
- The `split` environment is used for the last lines in the first block because these *really* belong to on equation. (If you don't like the position of the equation number, you could drop the`split` environment and just use `\notag` in one of the lines.)
- I didn't touch `F1` and `F2`.
  Your Mathematica output set them in the current text font (could be italics). Without the knowledge what they stand for, I would recommend using either `F_1` or `\mathrm{F}1`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\section{V. State-function of linearized system}
% compare output of F to results in section 1 and 3
We need only height so the equations gets much simplified,
now from the matrix-case to scalars so that
% we don't want to have a new paragraph starting here, so: no blank line!
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
      A' & =-\frac{ag}{A \sqrt{2 g h}}       \\
      B' & = \frac{2}{A}                     \\
\Delta u & = F1 + F2 - 1.2                   \\
\begin{split}
\Delta x & = h - a'                          \\
         & = h - \frac{(F1 + F2)^2}{2 a^2 g}
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
% if you leave this line blank, you get another paragraph
so
%
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
\partial_t x & = A' \Delta x - B' \Delta u\\
             & = - \frac{ag}{A \sqrt{2 g h}} \left(h - \frac{(F1 + F2)^2}{2 a^2 g}\right) 
                 - \frac{2}{A} \left(F1 + F2 - 1.2 \right). \\
\end{split}\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: ...discussion [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6491376#6491376).

Comment: @hhh Don't put `align` environments inside other math environments (in your instance `equation`). Only `split` can be used inside other math environment (but not `multiline`). I seriously recommend reading the [`amsmath` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf); this is explained on the very first pages, along with a few examples.

Comment: @hhh Furthermore, the `-ed` family can be also used inside other math environments but inner ampersands don't get aligned to outher ones (the `cases` environment is a special form of `aligned`).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to get well-formatted Mathematica-dump so I used basic eq-split -block like below. It is relatively slow to type them but, currently without better solution, I use this -- perhaps this could be automated somehow: deduce something from equations and make it look nice.

[image]

```
\section{V. State -function of linearized system}
% compare output of F to results in section 1 and 3

We need only height so the equations gets much simplified, now from the matrix -case to scalars so that 

\begin{equation}\begin{split}
A'&=-\frac{ag}{A\sqrt{2 g h}} \\
B'&=\frac{2}{A} \\
\Delta u&=F1+F2-1.2 \\
\Delta x&=h-a' \\
&=h-\frac{(F1+F2)^2}{2 a^2 g} \\
\end{split}\end{equation}

so 

\begin{equation}\begin{split}
\partial_tx &= A'\Delta x-B'\Delta u\\
&= \left(-\frac{ag}{A\sqrt{2 g h}}\right)\left(h-\frac{(F1+F2)^2}{2 a^2 g}\right)-\left(\frac{2}{A}\right)\left(F1+F2-1.2\right).\\
\end{split}\end{equation}
```