# breqn and hyperref breaking subnumcases environment when used together

Tags: hyperref, cases, breqn

I have an issue when using `cases`, `breqn` and `hyperref` together. This is my MWE

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{breqn} % For line breaks in some really long equations in another part of the document
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\begin{document}
\begin{subnumcases}{\label{eq:case} x =}
a+b, & example 1\\
c+d, & example 2.
\end{subnumcases}
This text refers to \ref{eq:case}.
\end{document}
```

When compiling my thesis with `breqn` loaded I get the image below, where apparently the label isn't set and x has disappeared.
[image: What I get]

When I don't load `breqn` I get the behaviour I want but at the expense of the equations that do require `breqn` later on in my thesis:
[image: What I want]

And when I don't load `hyperref` I also get useable output but with the links in the final PDF. Is there a way to keep `breqn` and `hyperref` without breaking my `subnumcases` environments?

Comment: The [package documentation](http://ctan.org/pkg/breqn) talks about option clashes, but if your problem sticks to breaking long equations, you could use the more-trusted `amsmath` environments, as discussed [in this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8936/how-to-break-a-long-equation).

Comment: What platform are you using ? With Ubuntu 12.04, Texlive 2012, I have different results (still none of them is correct): when x is visible, the label does not work, and vice versa (depending if `breqn` is loaded or not). Like Andrea, I recommand you to take a look at the `amsmath` package, in particular the environment split, cases and subequations.

Comment: I'm using TeXWorks with MikTeX on Windows 7.

And I'm leaning more toward removing `breqn` and doing as you say as it appears to be interfering with some `pgfplots` I have.

Answer (score 9):

Don't ask me how I found this out, I just drink too much coffee these days.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{breqn} % For line breaks in some really long equations in another part of the document
\usepackage{hyperref} 

% Patching the numcases environment from 
% cases.sty for compatibility with breqn+hyperref
% Source of problem: use of \box\z@, but \box\z@ somehow
% is used by some other macro at some point when breqn+hyperef
% are used.
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newbox\boxzero
\patchcmd{\numcases}{\setbox\z@}{\setbox\boxzero}{}{}
\patchcmd{\numcases}{\kern\wd\z@}{\kern\wd\boxzero}{}{}
\patchcmd{\endnumcases}{\displaystyle \box\z@}{\displaystyle\box\boxzero}{}{}
\let\endsubnumcases\endnumcases
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{subnumcases}{\label{eq:case}x =}
a+b, & example 1\\
c+d, & example 2.
\end{subnumcases}

This text refers to \ref{eq:case}.
\end{document}
```

Output:

> [image: cases]

Comment: Nice find! I still think that numbering cases separately is wrong, though.