# How to break long equations while keeping alignment?

Tags: equations, line-breaking, align, brackets

I have the following long equations:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
\begin{aligned}
(\chi_1|\chi_1)
&=\frac{1}{24}\left(\left(\chi_1(1)\right)^2+\left(\chi_1(b^2)\right)^2+2.\left(\chi_1(a)\right)^2+2.\left(\chi_1(a^3)\right)^2+2.\left(\chi_1(a^5)\right)^2+2.\left(\chi_1(a^2)\right)^2+2.\left(\chi_1(a^2b^2)\right)^2+6.\left(\chi_1(b)\right)^2+6.\left(\chi_1(ab)\right)^2\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{24}\left(\left(Sp(I_2)\right)^2+\left(Sp(B^2)\right)^2+2.\left(Sp(A_1)\right)^2+2.\left(Sp({A_1}^3)\right)^2+2.\left(Sp({A_1}^5)\right)^2+2.\left(Sp({A_1}^2)\right)^2+2.\left(Sp({A_1}^2B^2)\right)^2+6.\left(Sp(B)\right)^2+6.\left(Sp(A_1B)\right)^2\right)\\
\end{aligned}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to break the equations and keep the "=" aligned.

I tried this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
\begin{aligned}
(\chi_1|\chi_1)
&=\frac{1}{24}\left(\left(\chi_1(1)\right)^2+\left(\chi_1(b^2)\right)^2+2.\left(\chi_1(a)\right)^2+2.\left(\chi_1(a^3)\right)^2+2.\left(\chi_1(a^5)\right)^2+2.\left(\chi_1(a^2)\right)^2\\
& +2.\left(\chi_1(a^2b^2)\right)^2+6.\left(\chi_1(b)\right)^2+6.\left(\chi_1(ab)\right)^2\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{24}\left(\left(Sp(I_2)\right)^2+\left(Sp(B^2)\right)^2+2.\left(Sp(A_1)\right)^2+2.\left(Sp({A_1}^3)\right)^2+2.\left(Sp({A_1}^5)\right)^2+\\
& 2.\left(Sp({A_1}^2)\right)^2+2.\left(Sp({A_1}^2B^2)\right)^2+6.\left(Sp(B)\right)^2+6.\left(Sp(A_1B)\right)^2\right)\\
\end{aligned}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

But that ruins my bracket structure. In the end, I'd like to have something like this (of course the brackets don't have the correct height in the image):

[image: Equations]

Mind that the second part of the equation has to start from the first big bracket.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8936/how-to-break-a-long-equation

Comment: @Ruben: the split environment doesn't work (or I don't know how to use it): the brackets are still not correct. And how should I provide the alignement with the first big bracket?

Comment: In my eyes, that’s not the correct duplicate. But this and one of its many linked question should help (or not): [How to make `\left`, `\right` pairs of delimiter work over multiple lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21290) Though in your case, I’d just use `[` and `]` in their natural case, no need for `\left` and `\right` really.

Comment: By the way, for *one* equation on *multiple* lines with aligning, it is best to use the `equation` (or `equation*`) with the `split` environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest you make several changes. The first one will fix the error messages you're getting; the remaining ones should help make it easier for your readers to parse the material in the equations.

- You can't have a `\left(` ... `\right)` pair crossing a line break. In the first and third lines of the equation construct, replace the first `\left(` with `\Big[`, and in the second and fourth lines replace `\right)` with `\Big]`.
- The remaining  `\left(` ... `\right)` pairs -- I believe there are 18 of them... -- currently generate parentheses of varying sizes. This happens because not all of the expressions they enclose are large enough to trigger an increase in the size of the fences beyond the basic size. I suggest you change all 18 remaining `\left(` instructions to `\bigl(`, and all 18 remaining `\right)` instructions to `\bigr)`. This will ensure consistent sizing.
- The `Sp` terms in the third and fourth lines are probably math operators, right? If so, they should be typeset in an upright rather than italic font.
- In the first set of two lines, the first line has 6 additive terms and the second has 3; in the second set of two lines, the lines have 5 and 4 additive terms, respectively. I suggest you use the same number of terms across the two sets.
- Use `\mid` instead of `|` in the left-hand term. This will provide a bit of spacing around the vertical bar.
- To indicate multiplication, don't use a "dot". Use either `\cdot` or (better yet) omit the dots entirely.
- To provide some visual grouping, it's a good idea to indent the 2nd and 4th lines a bit relative to the 1st and 3rd lines. In the example below I use `\qquad` to indent the two lines; if that's not enough for you, you could try `\qquad\quad`.
- Last but not least, since you're already using the `amsmath` package, use the `align*` environment instead of nested `displaymath` and `aligned` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Sp}{Sp}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
(\chi_1\mid \chi_1)
&=\frac{1}{24}\Big[\bigl(\chi_1(1)\bigr)^2+\bigl(\chi_1(b^2)\bigr)^2+2\bigl(\chi_1(a)\bigr)^2+2\bigl(\chi_1(a^3)\bigr)^2+2\bigl(\chi_1(a^5)\bigr)^2\\
&\qquad +2\bigl(\chi_1(a^2)\bigr)^2+2\bigl(\chi_1(a^2b^2)\bigr)^2+6\bigl(\chi_1(b)\bigr)^2+6\bigl(\chi_1(ab)\bigr)^2\Big]\\
&=\frac{1}{24}\Big[\bigl(\Sp(I_2)\bigr)^2+\bigl(\Sp(B^2)\bigr)^2+2\bigl(\Sp(A_1)\bigr)^2+2\bigl(\Sp({A_1}^3)\bigr)^2+2\bigl(\Sp({A_1}^5)\bigr)^2\\
&\qquad  +2\bigl(\Sp({A_1}^2)\bigr)^2+2\bigl(\Sp({A_1}^2B^2)\bigr)^2+6\bigl(\Sp(B)\bigr)^2+6\bigl(\Sp(A_1B)\bigr)^2\Big]\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\phantom`s to move yourself into the correct spot, and avoid bracket-complications by using the "big" alternatives:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcommand{\FaSymb}{\chi_1}\newcommand{\FbSymb}{\text{Sp}}
\newcommand{\Fa}[1]{\FaSymb(#1)}
\newcommand{\Fb}[1]{\FbSymb(#1)}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  (\FaSymb \mid \FaSymb)
    & = \tfrac{1}{24}
        \Bigl(\bigl(\Fa{1}\bigr)^2
            + \bigl(\Fa{b^2}\bigr)^2
           + 2\bigl(\Fa{a}\bigr)^2
           + 2\bigl(\Fa{a^3}\bigr)^2
           + 2\bigl(\Fa{a^5}\bigr)^2
           + 2\bigl(\Fa{a^2}\bigr)^2 \\
    & \phantom{=\tfrac{1}{24}\Bigl(} + 2\bigl(\Fa{a^2b^2}\bigr)^2
      + 6\bigl(\Fa{b}\bigr)^2
      + 6\bigl(\Fa{ab}\bigr)^2\Bigr) \\
    & = \tfrac{1}{24}
        \Bigl(\bigl(\Fb{I_2}\bigr)^2
            + \bigl(\Fb{B^2}\bigr)^2
           + 2\bigl(\Fb{A_1}\bigr)^2
           + 2\bigl(\Fb{A_1^3}\bigr)^2
           + 2\bigl(\Fb{A_1^5}\bigr)^2 \\
    & \phantom{=\tfrac{1}{24}\Bigl(} + 2\bigl(\Fb{A_1^2}\bigr)^2
      + 2\bigl(\Fb{A_1^2B^2}\bigr)^2
      + 6\bigl(\Fb{B}\bigr)^2
      + 6\bigl(\Fb{A_1B}\bigr)^2\Bigr)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I defined `\Fa` and `\Fb` to promote [consistency](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764).

Answer (score 2):

Your second attempt didn't work because every `\left` has to be paired up with `\right` on the same line. To fix this, you can just use `\Bigl(` and `\Bigr)` instead. To get the alignment right, you can use the `IEEEtrantools` package (see [Section 3.5.2](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rClCl}
  (\chi_1|\chi_1)
  &=& \frac{1}{24}
      \Bigl(
           \left(\chi_1(1)\right)^2
        &+&\left(\chi_1(b^2)\right)^2
        +2.\left(\chi_1(a)\right)^2
        +2.\left(\chi_1(a^3)\right)^2
        +2.\left(\chi_1(a^5)\right)^2 \\
  & & &+&2.\left(\chi_1(a^2)\right)^2
        +2.\left(\chi_1(a^2b^2)\right)^2
        +6.\left(\chi_1(b)\right)^2
        +6.\left(\chi_1(ab)\right)^2
      \Bigr) \\
  &=& \frac{1}{24}
      \Bigl(
           \left(Sp(I_2)\right)^2
        &+&\left(Sp(B^2)\right)^2
        +2.\left(Sp(A_1)\right)^2
        +2.\left(Sp({A_1}^3)\right)^2
        +2.\left(Sp({A_1}^5)\right)^2 \\
  & & &+&2.\left(Sp({A_1}^2)\right)^2
        +2.\left(Sp({A_1}^2B^2)\right)^2
        +6.\left(Sp(B)\right)^2
        +6.\left(Sp(A_1B)\right)^2
      \Bigr)
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

[image]