# How to align an equation?

Tags: align

I am new to LaTeX. So, I am stuck with something which should be simple. I need to align this equation so that the last term which goes to the next line begins after the equal to sign, but I can't figure out how to do this? Here is my code:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{align*}
  log(Y_{it}) = c_i  + year_t + \beta_{1}rcs(MaxT_{it})} + \beta_{2}MinT_{it} +\beta_{3} log(SR_{it}) +\beta_{4}Rain_{it}  + 
                  \beta_{5}Share Irrigated_{it}
\end{align*}
\end{center}
```

Comment: You forgot the *alignment* character `&` while aligning.

Comment: Rubin I don't undertstand could you be specific. Where should the & character be placed? Can you give a example?

Comment: the `align` environment can be understood as a table with 2 columns. Do you know how to handle tables in LaTeX? BTW: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Yes I do so you have to insert & between consecutive values that go in the 2 columns. So where can I insert & here to get my desired result? I did play around but didn't ahve any luck

Comment: Can't you search over here for `align` and see how it works? Or even better, read the `amsmath` [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf)?

Answer (score 2):

Some additional changes are needed to make this equation readable. Because I don't know the nature of elements, `\mathrm` is only a suggestion. Maybe some of summands should be changed `\mathit`. Probably `rcs` is also not r times c times s, hence it should be changed in the suggested way. Note also, that `center` is meaningless here.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{align*}
 % log(Y_{it}) = c_i  + year_t + \beta_{1}rcs(MaxT_{it})} + \beta_{2}MinT_{it} +\beta_{3} log(SR_{it}) +\beta_{4}Rain_{it}  + 
\log(Y_{it}) &  =  c_i  + \mathrm{year}_t + \beta_{1}rcs(\mathrm{Max}T_{\mathrm{it}})+ \beta_{2}\mathrm{MinT}_{\mathrm{it}} +\beta_{3} \log(SR_{\mathrm{it}}) +\beta_{4}\mathrm{Rain}_{\mathrm{it}}  + {}\\
       &    \quad {}+       \beta_{5}\mathrm{Share Irrigated}_{\mathrm{it}}
\end{align*}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `center` doesn't really do anything in this case, does it? Displayed math is centered by default anyway.

Comment: is there a reason that one `T` is roman and one italic?

Comment: @barbarabeeton These are only suggestions, that something should be changed.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I forgot adding this remark. Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't put the subscript `it` stuff in `\mathrm` at all.

Comment: @Mico If `it` is `i` times `t`, then of course not. But if it is a new parameter?

Answer (score 2):

As @karlkoeller stated in his comment, probabilly it would be sufficent to read the AMS documentation. However, if you need help to figure out how the `align` environment works (which I understand, reading your comments, is the main point), you won't get rejected. And as far as this has not been asked yet:

The `align` environment (as matrices and tables) aligns content using `&` to indicate the point at which the lines should be aligned, and `\\` declares a line break. In general it is used like

```
\begin{align*}
  r & = (x+p)(x+q)\\
    & = x^2 + (p+q)x + pq
\end{align*}
```

(Note: There is no need to use the `center` environment because `align` and friends acess display math mode.)

Now, in your specific case you only need to split your equation over several lines instead of aligning it to several equal signs. For this have a look at [How to break a long equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8936/how-to-break-a-long-equation) or @PrzemysławScherwents answer, which is summarizing the last mentioned post.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use *text-italic* rather than math-italic mode for variable names.

The overall equation seems to be a bit too long to fit comfortably on one line. I suggest you insert a line break after `\beta_{3} \log(\textit{SR}_{it})`.

Note also that nothing (at least nothing good) is achieved by encasing an `align*` environment in a `center` environment; hence, just leave off the `center`-related instructions. Separately, if you type `\log` rather than simply `log`, the "operator name" is set in an upright roman font, which is customary style in many math (and statistics, econometrics, etc) settings. (Incidentally, I can't tell what the function/meaning of `rcs` might be so I've given it a text-italics font for now. I've also assigned a coefficient to the `year` variable...)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\log(Y_{it}) 
&= c_i  + \gamma\textit{year}_t 
  + \beta_{1}\textit{rcs}(\textit{MaxT}_{it})
  + \beta_{2}\textit{MinT}_{it} 
  +\beta_{3} \log(\textit{SR}_{it}) \\
&\quad+\beta_{4}\textit{Rain}_{it}  + 
  \beta_{5}\textit{ShareIrrigated}_{it}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you all for the responses and help. I have lots to learn and thanks for pointing me to the resources.

Comment: @Ridhima - good to know you found these answers helpful. Please feel free to upvote and/or accept answers you found particularly useful.