# Line breaking in equation

Tags: equations, line-breaking

This is the equation I want to write in LaTex:
[image]

I have read [these advices](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8936/how-to-break-a-long-equation), but for split and multilined commands it says that they are undefined (and also for multiline, but nevertheless this is not suitable for me). Is there another possibility how to break line?

Comment: What's the meaning of the semicolons? Do they signify that `V_{i,j}` is equal to the material to the left of the semicolon if the statement on the right is true? If that's the case (pun intended), have you tried using the `cases` environment provided by the `amsmath` package?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Semicolon separates only condition. Cases is something that I am looking for, but it generates only left { and no right }. If it is possible to add ending }, then it will be great.

Answer (score 2):

The `empheq`package (which loads `mathtools` and `amsmath`) lets put whatever you want on the left or on the right of a group of equations. So here is another solution, with the `gather*`environment:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bothsides]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
    \usepackage[overload]{empheq}


    \begin{document}

    \begin{gather*}[left ={ V_{i,j} = \empheqlbrace},  right = \empheqrbrace ]
           a + b  = c + d \\
            ∫_0¹ x² \ \mathrm{d}x   = \dfrac{1}{3}\\
           \nabla u  =  0
    \end{gather*}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since you've noted in a comment that the semicolons are there to denote an "if ..." relationship, I would suggest that you display the material in two separate columns, with `;` replaced with `if` at the start of the second column.

Furthermore, since the same, fairly complicated expression occurs five times between the curly braces, I suggest you define it beforehand and give it a shorthand, say, `\widehat{W}`. (You're obviously free to come up with a more suitable shorthand symbol!) Then use either an `array` environment or a `dcases` environment to state what `V_{ij}` is, with `\widehat{W}` -- or whatever symbol you end up choosing -- making its appearance five times.

This setup -- first, define the complicated expression; second, use it repeatedly in the statement of what `V_{ij}` is -- should let the reader focus more easily on the structure of the argument.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}    
\begin{document}
Let $\displaystyle\widehat{W}\equiv W_{j}\ln\biggl( 1 + 
  \frac{G_{i,j} \abs{h_{i,j}}^2 P_{i,j}} {\sigma_{i,j}^2} \biggr)$. Then
\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5} % more space between lines to mimic display style
  V_{i,j} =
  \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
     (Q_{1}D_{i}^{d} + Q_{2}D_{i}^{o}) \widehat{W}
        & \text{if } D_{i}^{d} + D_{i}^{o} \leq \widehat{W}\\
     Q_{1}D_{i}^{d} \widehat{W}
        & \text{if } D_{i}^{d} \leq \widehat{W} < D_{i}^{d} + D_{i}^{o}\\
     0 
        & \text{if } \widehat{W} < D_{i}^{d}
  \end{array}\right\}
\]

Or, using the \texttt{dcases} environment:
\[
  V_{i,j} =
  \begin{dcases} % dcases environment is provided by the mathtools package
     (Q_{1}D_{i}^{d} + Q_{2}D_{i}^{o}) \widehat{W}
        & \text{if } D_{i}^{d} + D_{i}^{o} \leq \widehat{W}\\
     Q_{1}D_{i}^{d} \widehat{W}
        & \text{if } D_{i}^{d} \leq \widehat{W} < D_{i}^{d} + D_{i}^{o}\\
     0 
        & \text{if } \widehat{W} < D_{i}^{d}      
  \end{dcases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a smart way of doing it!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  V_{i,j} =
  \begin{Bmatrix}
    \displaystyle (Q_{1}D_{i}^{d} + Q_{2}D_{i}^{o})W_{j}\ln{\mkern -7mu}\left(1 + \frac{G_{i,j}\abs{h_{i,j}}^{2}P_{i,j}}{\sigma_{i,j}^{2}}\right){\mkern -5mu}; D_{i}^{d} + D_{i}^{o} \leq W_{j}\ln{\mkern -7mu}\left(1 + \frac{G_{i,j}\abs{h_{i,j}}^{2}P_{i,j}}{\sigma_{i,j}^{2}}\right){\mkern -5mu}\\[3ex]
    \displaystyle Q_{1}D_{i}^{d}W_{j}\ln{\mkern -7mu}\left(1 + \frac{G_{i,j}\abs{h_{i,j}}^{2}P_{i,j}}{\sigma_{i,j}^{2}}\right){\mkern -5mu}; D_{i}^{d} \leq W_{j}\ln{\mkern -7mu}\left(1 + \frac{G_{i,j}\abs{h_{i,j}}^{2}P_{i,j}}{\sigma_{i,j}^{2}}\right){\mkern -5mu} < D_{i}^{d} + D_{i}^{o}\\[3ex]
    \displaystyle 0; W_{j}\ln{\mkern -7mu}\left(1 + \frac{G_{i,j}\abs{h_{i,j}}^{2}P_{i,j}}{\sigma_{i,j}^{2}}\right){\mkern -5mu} < D_{i}^{d}
  \end{Bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

P.S. I've added [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) to avoid the equation going into the margin.

**Update**

If you want all the math in the document to be written in display style, you can declare `\everymath{\displaystyle}`;

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\everymath{\displaystyle}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  V_{i,j} =
  \begin{Bmatrix}
    (Q_{1}D_{i}^{d} + Q_{2}D_{i}^{o})W_{j}\ln{\mkern -7mu}\left(1 + \frac{G_{i,j}\abs{h_{i,j}}^{2}P_{i,j}}{\sigma_{i,j}^{2}}\right){\mkern -5mu}; D_{i}^{d} + D_{i}^{o} \leq W_{j}\ln{\mkern -7mu}\left(1 + \frac{G_{i,j}\abs{h_{i,j}}^{2}P_{i,j}}{\sigma_{i,j}^{2}}\right){\mkern -5mu}\\[3ex]
    Q_{1}D_{i}^{d}W_{j}\ln{\mkern -7mu}\left(1 + \frac{G_{i,j}\abs{h_{i,j}}^{2}P_{i,j}}{\sigma_{i,j}^{2}}\right){\mkern -5mu}; D_{i}^{d} \leq W_{j}\ln{\mkern -7mu}\left(1 + \frac{G_{i,j}\abs{h_{i,j}}^{2}P_{i,j}}{\sigma_{i,j}^{2}}\right){\mkern -5mu} < D_{i}^{d} + D_{i}^{o}\\[3ex]
    0; W_{j}\ln{\mkern -7mu}\left(1 + \frac{G_{i,j}\abs{h_{i,j}}^{2}P_{i,j}}{\sigma_{i,j}^{2}}\right){\mkern -5mu} < D_{i}^{d}
  \end{Bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of inserting all those (negative) `\mkern`s by hand, you could load the `mleftright` package and issue the instruction `\mleftright` in the preamble. Doing so will get rid of all the extra white space that's otherwise inserted by `\left` and `\right`. Actually, I'd argue that the parents generated by `\left` and `\right` are too tall, typographically speaking; sizing the fences as `\bigg[lr]` or possibly even as `\Big[lr]` may be more desirable.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the hint. I think the spacing is too small so I'll stick to the manual approach.

Comment: Quite difficult solution in the first look – with that mkern command. But this looks like it should. I will try it with \mleftright.

Comment: @TA_Kosice You don't have to use `\mkern` it it looks wierd without.

Comment: I've borrowed your code for my answer (and, of course, upvoted yours...).

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the `mathtools` package to obtain the `multlined` environment.

Anyway, the `Bmatrix` environment from the same package (and from `amsmath`, of which `mathtools` is an extension) may be suitable to you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
V_{i,j}=\begin{Bmatrix} Q_1 \\ Q_2 \\ Q_3\end{Bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of `Q_1`, `Q_2` and `Q_3`, you may enter your own formulas.

Comment: actually, `multlined` requires `mathtools`.  however, `gathered` (which *is* in `amsmath`) would seem to be more appropriate, since it centers all the lines rather than staggering them from left to right.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Sorry for the confusion, I've updated my answer. Anyway, I've used `mathtools` instead of `amsmath` for a long time by now, so I'm sometimes a bit confused about which command/environment is in the first package and not in the second package :-)

Comment: I had loaded mathtools package before I tried it, but result was undefined sequence. Usage of matrix – this solution did not come to my mind. But not bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array:

```
\begin{align*}
    V_{i,j}=\left\lbrace\begin{array}{c}%
                First line\\
                Second line\\
                Third line
             \end{array}\right\rbrace
\end{align*}
```