# split equation in multiple lines

Tags: equations, amsthm, amssymb

I am a new Latex user,I have loaded these two math equation in my Latex documents and i want to split an equation i have into multiple line

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
```

I am reading this topic for breaking the lines over multiple

[How to break a long equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8936/how-to-break-a-long-equation)

although what ever i do it does not allow me to compile

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[authoryear,preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{xx}
\begin{split}
A&= 1 + 2 + \\
& 3 +4 +6
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}

\endinput
```

So

```
\begin{equation}
A = 1 + 2 + 3 +4 +6
\end{equation}
```

I want to place them/break the equation in two lines and retain the format of numbering and equal placing beneath.

i tried

```
\begin{equation}
A = 1 + 2 + \\
3 +4 +6
\end{equation}
```

Although it does not work

When i use `\begin{multline}`

```
\begin{multline}
A = 1 + 2 + \\
3 +4 +6
\end{multline}
```

and the following errors

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment multline undefined.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \begin{multline}
```

! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{multline}.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... \end{multline}

Though i get the equation broken it is not numbered, or has a one line distance from my text as the `\begin{equation}`
Also tried this example as kindly suggested

```
\begin{equation}\label{xx}
\begin{split}
A&= 1 + 2 + \\
& 3 +4 +6
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

and obtaining these

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment split undefined.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \begin{split}
! Misplaced alignment tab character &. A&
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.<recently read> & &
! LaTeX Error: \begin{equation} on input line 142 ended by \end{split}.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \end{split}
```

Have i missed anything?

Comment: `multline` is its own displayed math environment and should be used on its own, not inside `equation`. Lots of good introductory material is included in the [Short Math Guide for LaTeX](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf).

Comment: @PaulGessler I used it alone but it gave more errors in the compilers most of them saying ! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$ ...l N(\sigma;\lambda;\theta;t)}{\partial t} over multiple lines

Comment: @PaulGessler although as far as I can see the \begin{equation} give s me a better visual result, that is why i am keen of using that one

Comment: @PaulGessler I had a look in the document, thank you for the link. I copied and pasted their example exactly as is, but i still get errors, does it have to do with the package i am using?

Comment: I can't say, because you haven't provided a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: (a) `multiline` is defined by the `amsmath` package, (b) it is a top level environment and can't be embedded in `equation`, use `split` instead (also from the `amsmath` package).

Comment: @PaulGessler I tried to give a better MWE, i hope it is a bit more helpful, sorry for the previous post if it was confusing

Comment: @AndrewSwann I tried as i posted in the example above but no luck in that.

Comment: This is still not an MWE... it needs `\documentclass{...}`; we need to see which packages you've loaded; and `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` are missing. Did you read the answers at the MWE link? My guess is that you haven't loaded the `amsmath` package. But again, without MWE, no way to tell for sure.

Comment: I have posted a solution below, it will work with your use of `elsarticle` too, just remember to issue `\usepackage{mathtools}`

Comment: the simplest answer to this is that you haven't got `\usepackage{amsmath}`. which is where `split` is defined.

Comment: Thank you all for your patience and help, i think i understood, that i am not limited by the packages set which was my main concern

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest you use a `split` environment, which in contrast to `multline` may be used a subenvironment of `equation`.  You need to specify an alignment point on each line with `&` and separate lines with `\\`.  In this case the first line should be move left relative to the others and the package `mathtools` provides a convenient command for this:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \label{wave kinematic}
  \begin{split}
    \MoveEqLeft
    \frac{\partial N(\sigma;\lambda;\theta;t)}{\partial t}
    + \frac{\partial C_{g,\lambda}N(\sigma;\lambda;\theta;t)}
    {\partial \lambda} \\
    &+ \cos\phi^{-1} \cdot
    \frac{\partial C_{f,\phi}N(\sigma;\lambda;\theta;t)}{\partial
    \phi} \\
    &+ \frac{\partial C_{f,\theta}N(\sigma;\lambda;\theta;t)}{\partial
    \theta} 
    + \frac{\partial C_{f,\sigma}N(\sigma;\lambda;\theta;t)}{\partial
    \sigma}  
    = \frac{S(\sigma;\theta;\lambda;\varphi;t)}{\sigma}
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I have split across three lines for clarity.  If you wanted to just split in two parts, then `multlined` (notice the extra `d`) from the `mathtools` package would be a simpler solution:

[image: multlined sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \label{wave kinematic}
  \begin{multlined}
    \frac{\partial N(\sigma;\lambda;\theta;t)}{\partial t}
    + \frac{\partial C_{g,\lambda}N(\sigma;\lambda;\theta;t)}
    {\partial \lambda} 
    + \cos\phi^{-1} \cdot
    \frac{\partial C_{f,\phi}N(\sigma;\lambda;\theta;t)}{\partial
    \phi} \\
    + \frac{\partial C_{f,\theta}N(\sigma;\lambda;\theta;t)}{\partial
    \theta} 
    + \frac{\partial C_{f,\sigma}N(\sigma;\lambda;\theta;t)}{\partial
    \sigma}  
    = \frac{S(\sigma;\theta;\lambda;\varphi;t)}{\sigma}
  \end{multlined}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

All the above works with `elsarticle` class in your updated question.  E.g. the first version becomes:

```
\documentclass[authoryear,preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \label{wave kinematic}
  \begin{split}
    \MoveEqLeft
    \frac{\partial N(\sigma;\lambda;\theta;t)}{\partial t}
    + \frac{\partial C_{g,\lambda}N(\sigma;\lambda;\theta;t)}
    {\partial \lambda} \\
    &+ \cos\phi^{-1} \cdot
    \frac{\partial C_{f,\phi}N(\sigma;\lambda;\theta;t)}{\partial
    \phi} \\
    &+ \frac{\partial C_{f,\theta}N(\sigma;\lambda;\theta;t)}{\partial
    \theta} 
    + \frac{\partial C_{f,\sigma}N(\sigma;\lambda;\theta;t)}{\partial
    \sigma}  
    = \frac{S(\sigma;\theta;\lambda;\varphi;t)}{\sigma}
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much, although if i may ask can i ask if multiple packages can be used.
I am trying to learn Latex at the same time , thank you for your patience

Comment: Yes you can load several different packages.

Comment: `mathtools` helps my case. I was using `amsthm` but it produces weird formatting under Elsevier’s template. Switching to `mathtools` resolves the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you tried doing with `multine` but this seems OK:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}

\begin{multline}\label{wave kinematic}
\frac{\partial N(\sigma;\lambda;\theta;t)}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial C_{g,\lambda}N(\sigma;\lambda;\theta;t)}{\partial \lambda} +
\cos\phi^{-1}\cdot \frac{\partial C_{f,\phi}N(\sigma;\lambda;\theta;t)}{\partial \phi}+\\
\frac{\partial C_{f,\theta}N(\sigma;\lambda;\theta;t)}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial C_{f,\sigma}N(\sigma;\lambda;\theta;t)}{\partial \sigma} = \frac{S(\sigma;\theta;\lambda;\varphi;t}{\sigma}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

Using this you obtain:

[image]

Btw, you seem to be missing a bracket on the RHS -- and I deleted an extraneous comma after the `\begin{equation}`.

Comment: Andrew,@Andrew,i used \begin{multline} after the \begin{equation}, i pasted your solution and i get an error which i have given in the question as a new edit. I am using the package math of \usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

Comment: @George I posted the self-contained code example above so that you could see one of doing this that works. My code compiles and, looking at it, it doesn't contain `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`. Why don't you try leaving this out?

Comment: i will try it as well, i was fortunate to get many helpful answers. thank you for your time