# Fitting unbreakable large equation on one line in a twocolumn layout

Tags: equations, two-column

I have an equation in my document which is unbreakable and does not fit on one line using the `twocolumn` global option. Am I forced to shrink the text size here? And how do I go about doing it? `\resizebox` does not function in math mode.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Bbn2CZj.png?1]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{q_\mathrm{total}=0}^{q_A+N_A+q_B+N_B-2}\left(\sum_{q_A=0}^{q_\mathrm{total}}\left(\binom{q_A+N_A-1}{q_A}\binom{q_B+N_B-1}{q_B}\right)\right)x^{q_\mathrm{total}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `\small` or whatever works before the equation, or just simply introduce variables for the subterms so it fits

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Resizebox should work.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
\resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{$\sum_{q_\mathrm{total}=0}^{q_A+N_A+q_B+N_B-2}\left(\sum_{q_A=0}^{q_\mathrm{total}}\left(\binom{q_A+N_A-1}{q_A}\binom{q_B+N_B-1}{q_B}\right)\right)x^{q_\mathrm{total}}$}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```

Or maybe consider [splitting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8936/how-to-break-a-long-equation) your equation.

Comment: It's what the OP asked for, but arbitrarily scaling text so it fits in a space is so evil :-(

Comment: @DavidCarlisle From a typographic-aesthetic point of view? Or personal preference?

Comment: @1010011010 All of above. It shouts as *hey I couldn't fit it here so I scaled it, deal with it*. Valid but says much about you instead of the equation :P

Comment: @1010011010 just ask yourself how many professionally typeset works you have seen where text elements are using arbitrarily scaled fonts to make the element fit the space rather than one of a limited number of matched design sizes.

Comment: @percusse I may have chosen the wrong layout then.... `:-(` Going back from `twocolumn` would take days.

Comment: @1010011010 Not really. There is always a better way. Logical argument chain is never too complicated to state concisely. Similar to what @tohecz said, define `n=q_a+N_A-1` and `m=q_b+N_B-1` then you only need `n` and `m` for the sum limits and binomials (or whatever single letter abbreviation you wish). It should then fit.

Comment: @percusse There's a second reasonable option: define `A(x,y)=\binom{x+N_A-1}{x}\binom{y+N_B-1}{y}` (or something like that, I'm a bit lost in the variables) in a separate displayed equation. That, with the removal of all the spurious parentheses, would likely be enough. /looking for my **PLEASE DO NOT DO THIS** banner/

Comment: use \columnwidth within resizebox

Answer (score 36):

The `cuted` package (from the `sttools` bundle) can temporarily leave two columns mode with its `strip` environment. An example with the equation entered in the second column:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{mathtools, cuted}
\usepackage{lipsum, color}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\lipsum[1]

\textsf{\color{red}Equation entered here: }

\begin{strip}
\begin{equation}
  \sum_{q_\mathrm{total}=0}^{q_A+N_A+q_B+N_B-2}\left(\sum_{q_A=0}^{q_\mathrm{total}}\left(\binom{q_A+N_A-1}{q_A}\binom{q_B+N_B-1}{q_B}\right)\right)x^{q_\mathrm{total}}
\end{equation}
\end{strip}

Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\lipsum[3-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this example shows the wide display entered in the first column.  the original question shows it occurring in the second column.  can you adjust your example to reproduce that situation?

Comment: @barbara beeton: see my updated answer.

Comment: Is this solution better than the `widetext` environment?

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś: I don't know this environment, so I can't really tell. However, I've just read on this site that `widetext` is based on the `strip` environment.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you have a much better option than this. Btw, you seem to use `q_A` for two different things.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{q_\mathrm{tot}=0}^{Q_A+Q_B-2}\sum_{q_A=0}^{q_\mathrm{tot}}{\textstyle\binom{Q_A-1}{q_A}\binom{Q_B-1}{q_B}}x^{q_\mathrm{tot}},
\end{equation}
where $Q_A=q_A+N_A$ and $Q_B=q_B+N_B$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico Well, it doesn't hurt :p But you're right that it should not be there. Thanks for pointing out :)