# How to create the long equations in two columns paper

Tags: equations

The equation I want to display is too long to put in one column, so I prefer to make it in the whole two columns like the following format of equation(47)
[image]

including the two lines above and under equation (47).  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: please add a minimal working example of your code we need to know the documentclass ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Does [Fitting unbreakable large equation on one line in a twocolumn layout](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/197214/32888) help?

Comment: Adding to those answers: You could also use a widetext - environment around your equation. I think its the go-to way for some journals (i.e. using revtex). This will result in slightly different separating lines, I dont know if thats important to you.

Comment: Thanks, Adam, It really what I want. By the way, do you know how to draw these two separate lines as shown above?

Comment: @Bort, unfortunately, I am writing a paper submitted to IEEE, where widetext is not compatible with IEEEtrans.