# How to create the long equations in two columns paper

Tags: equations

I have a long equation that need to put in two columns-type format. The template I use is IEEEtran. Here is the minimal document in original style:

```
\documentclass[journal,letter]{IEEEtran}

%--------------------- for math formulas-------------------------
\usepackage{mathtools,lipsum,cuted}
\setlength\stripsep{3pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}     
\usepackage{amssymb}                       
\usepackage{mathrsfs}                          
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{bm}     %bold for Greek symbols
\renewcommand\eqref[1]{(\ref{#1})}
\setlength{\jot}{5pt} 


\begin{document}
text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before 

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
    \mathbf{F}(\delta_k) = \begin{bmatrix}
        F(\delta_k) & & & & \\ \Gamma(\delta_k)F_L & F(\delta_k)+\Gamma(\delta_k)F_F & & & \\ & \Gamma(\delta_k)F_L & F(\delta_k)+\Gamma(\delta_k)F_F & & \\ & & \ddots & \ddots &\\ & & & \Gamma(\delta_k)F_L & F(\delta_k)+\Gamma(\delta_k)F_F \end{bmatrix} \medskip
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after 

\end{document}
```

[image]

we can see that this matrix is too wide to put in one column. So I use \cut package instructed by another post on this forum.

Here is the modified code:

```
\documentclass[journal,letter]{IEEEtran}

%--------------------- for math formulas-------------------------
\usepackage{mathtools,lipsum,cuted}
\setlength\stripsep{3pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}     
\usepackage{amssymb}                       
\usepackage{mathrsfs}                          
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{bm}     %bold for Greek symbols
\renewcommand\eqref[1]{(\ref{#1})}
\setlength{\jot}{5pt} 


\begin{document}
text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before 

\begin{strip}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
    \mathbf{F}(\delta_k) = \begin{bmatrix}
        F(\delta_k) & & & & \\ \Gamma(\delta_k)F_L & F(\delta_k)+\Gamma(\delta_k)F_F & & & \\ & \Gamma(\delta_k)F_L & F(\delta_k)+\Gamma(\delta_k)F_F & & \\ & & \ddots & \ddots &\\ & & & \Gamma(\delta_k)F_L & F(\delta_k)+\Gamma(\delta_k)F_F \end{bmatrix} \medskip
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{strip}

text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after 

\end{document}
```

and the format is like this
[image]

It can be seen that the text before the equation will fill all two columns and then equation displays. So my question is how to keep the text before the equation still fill just one column like the original format and just make the equation span in two columns?

Thanks.

Comment: If you can't find a solution try to make this matrix at top or bottom of page.

Answer (score 3):

Without concern, what happens, when text in column is longer than one column:

```
\documentclass[journal,letter]{IEEEtran}
%--------------------- for math formulas-------------------------
\usepackage{mathtools,lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{bm}     %bold for Greek symbols
\renewcommand\eqref[1]{(\ref{#1})}
\setlength{\jot}{5pt}
%--------------------- for wide math formulas --------------------
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{calc}
    \begin{document}
text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before text-before
\begin{adjustwidth}{0pt}{-\linewidth+\columnsep}
    \begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
\mathbf{F}(\delta_k) = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
    F(\delta_k) & & & & \\ 
    \Gamma(\delta_k)F_L & F(\delta_k)+\Gamma(\delta_k)F_F & & & \\ 
                & \Gamma(\delta_k)F_L & F(\delta_k)+\Gamma(\delta_k)F_F & & \\ 
                & & \ddots & \ddots &\\ & & & \Gamma(\delta_k)F_L & F(\delta_k)+\Gamma(\delta_k)F_F 
\end{bmatrix}\medskip
    \end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{adjustwidth}
text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after text-after
    \end{document}
```

This gives:
[image]
Caution: at text  longer than one column, it will overwrite equation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am writing a journal paper, in which the text of course is more than one column. Is there any other available solution for this? Anyway, thank you for your help~

Comment: Then yo already have good solution -- use of package `cuted`. Other solution, as far as I know, doesn't exist. Or broke equation into two line as I show in my answer in `Shrinking or splitting some equations in a group of equations`.

Comment: Thanks, I also prefer to use cuted environment, but you found that it will change the order of the origional text. The ideal format I want like in my another post of the same question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/259178/how-to-create-the-long-equations-in-two-columns-paper    you can see the text order is not changed. Thank you~