# Long equation spanning two-columns that occurs in right column

Tags: equations, two-column

**I am trying to achieve the formatting of Eq. 29 shown in the figure below. Specifically:**

**1. this is a long equation that occurs in the right column of a two-column document**

**2. the equation is typeset to span both columns**

**3. the text in the left column before the equation continues BELOW the equation**

[image]

I have tried the following strategies suggested on TeX.SE and other sites, and none of them produce the desired result. I include an image of the result to show why each is unsatisfactory for my application.

**1. Using the strip environment from the cuted package: the text of the equation overlaps the text in the left-column (specifically, it overlaps a footnote)**

[image]

and in other examples I have seen of this (below image is annotated from [How to create the long equations in two columns paper](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/259363/18450)) the text flows from left column to right above the equation and then left to right below the equation, which is not the desired flow I am after.

[image]

**2. Placing the equation in a figure* environment: this causes the equation to float so it doesn't appear where it is discussed (note that Eq. 26 floats to the next page and therefore shows up after Eq. 27)**

[image]

**3. Using a minipage: to make this appear in the right location I have to use a kludge and insert it earlier in the document, which makes the equation numbering incorrect (I imagine I could add insult to injury by fiddling with the equation counter back and forth, but I was hoping for a solution that didn't require two wrong turns to make a right), it also overlaps the text in the right column.**

[image]

**4. Using the multicol package: all of the examples I have seen for this approach (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33022911/1181402) show the text flows from the left-column to the right column above the equation and then restart in the left column below the equation, which is not the desired text flow. Moreover, when I tried to use it, it also had the undesired side effect of transforming the single-column foot-notes span two columns.**

[image]

Any suggestions for achieving the desired formatting shown in the first image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hallmark of fine typography is that it makes the material "look good"  *without* drawing undue attention to itself. I can think of two analogies involving people. First, consider a recital by a famous singer (opera star?) that's accompanied by a talented pianist. If anybody remembers the work of the pianist a few days after the event, then it's almost certainly because the pianist managed to mess up badly at some point during the evening. Second, consider the work of a wedding photographer at some fancy wedding. If people remember the photographer, it's likely because he/she messed up badly. Don't believe me? YouTube has hundreds (thousands?) of "funny" postings of weddings in which the photographer messed up one way or another...

Creating a long/wide equation that spans both columns of a two-column document pretty much flies in the face of everything that fine (math) typography stands for. Just because LaTeX happens to provide the tools that let you create a long/wide equation that spans both columns in no way implies that you *should* create an object that shouts out loud "Look at me, here I am! I'm damn good-looking! Really! Keep looking at me! Ignore all the stuff above and below me! I'm so much more important!" Trust me, you do *not* want your paper to be remembered by readers as "Oh, that quaint paper with a couple of super-wide equations. I can't really remember anything about the paper, other than the fact that it had a few super-wide equations." If nothing else, such papers tend not to get cited a lot...

For the use case at hand, it's actually straightforward to rearrange the material so that it can typeset via two stand-alone equations, each fitting nicely within the width of the column.

[image]

You're obviously free to choose a different symbol than `Q`...

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % or some other suitable font
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text
\newcommand\q[1]{q^{}_{\! #1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3] % filler text

Put 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
Q&= \q{A4}\q{C1}-\q{A1}\q{C4} + \q{A3}\q{C2}-\q{A2}\q{C3} \\
 &\quad+\q{B4}\q{D1}-\q{B1}\q{D4} + \q{B3}\q{D2}-\q{B2}\q{D3} \,. 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Then
\begin{equation}
\xi^{}_C=2\arctan\bigl(Q/(\q{A}\cdot\q{C}+\q{B}\cdot\q{D})\bigr)
+2\pi k
\end{equation}

\lipsum[2][2-4] % more filler text

\end{document}
```