# Split equation into multiple lines

Tags: equations, line-breaking, multline

I am trying to split a long equation into lines as explained in one of the answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8936/how-to-break-a-long-equation) using `multline` (`amsmath` package:

```
\begin{multline}
    m(X)=1.00 \cdot 0.94 \cdot 1.30 \cdot 1.30 \cdot 1.21 \cdot 1.00 \cdot 1.07 \cdot 1.00 & 1.29 \cdot 0.86 \cdot 1.00 \cdot 0.95 \cdot 1.00 \cdot 0.91 \cdot 1.23 = 2.4262
\end{multline}
```

However when compiling I am getting an error on the last line saying:

> Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
>
> You have written too many alignment tabs in a table, causing one of
>   them to be turned into a line break. Make sure you have specified the
>   correct number of columns in your table.

I can't figure out what's wrong. Also, a magic number `(2.1)` is being displayed right after the last term of the equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`multline` doesn't use any alignment points, indicated by `&`, only linebreaks, indicated by `\\`.

Replace the `&` in your code by `\cdot{} \\`. The `\cdot` was missing, the `{}` is to get proper spacing.

About the number, I don't know why you say "magic". by default `multline` is a numbered equation, if you don't want numbering use `multline*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\begin{document}
Numbered:
\begin{multline}
    m(X)=1.00 \cdot 0.94 \cdot 1.30 \cdot 1.30 \cdot 1.21 \cdot 1.00 \cdot 1.07 \cdot 1.00 \cdot{} \\ 1.29 \cdot 0.86 \cdot 1.00 \cdot 0.95 \cdot 1.00 \cdot 0.91 \cdot 1.23 = 2.4262
\end{multline}
Or an unnumbered version:
\begin{multline*}
    m(X)=1.00 \cdot 0.94 \cdot 1.30 \cdot 1.30 \cdot 1.21 \cdot 1.00 \cdot 1.07 \cdot 1.00 \cdot{} \\ 1.29 \cdot 0.86 \cdot 1.00 \cdot 0.95 \cdot 1.00 \cdot 0.91 \cdot 1.23 = 2.4262
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

[image]