# overfull hbox in equation, can't work out why?

Tags: math-mode

I'm getting an "overfull hbox" error on the follow code,..I've tried line breaks in all kinds of places but I can't seem to fix it. Please help!

```
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial M_u}{\partial z} = E_u - D_u \\
\frac{\partial (M_u s_u)}{\partial z} =  E_u \overline{s} - D_u s_u + L_v 
\overline{\rho} c_u \\
\frac{\partial (M_u q_u)}{\partial z} = E_u \overline{q} - D_u q_u  - 
\overline{\rho} c_u \\
\frac{\partial (M_u l)}{\partial z} = - D_u l + \overline{\rho} c_u - 
\overline{\rho} G_p \\
\end{equation}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use ``\\`` within an `equation` environment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8936/how-to-break-a-long-equation

Comment: You could replace equation with multline from the amsmath package and all will be fine.

Comment: I did what you said and it worked, thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 3):

Using the following code I got no overfull hbox error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial M_u}{\partial z} = E_u - D_u \\
\frac{\partial (M_u s_u)}{\partial z} =  E_u \overline{s} - D_u s_u + L_v 
\overline{\rho} c_u \\
\frac{\partial (M_u q_u)}{\partial z} = E_u \overline{q} - D_u q_u  - 
\overline{\rho} c_u \\
\frac{\partial (M_u l)}{\partial z} = - D_u l + \overline{\rho} c_u - 
\overline{\rho} G_p \\
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Maybe the problem is because your defined margins are shorter with respect to the default margins in the `minimal` document class.

As Au101 said, you should not use `\\` on a `equation` environment. If you want the equations to be in different lines and numbered, you could use the `align` (or `align*` to appear without numbers) environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial M_u}{\partial z} 
    &= E_u - D_u \\
\frac{\partial (M_u s_u)}{\partial z} 
    &= E_u \overline{s} - D_u s_u + L_v \overline{\rho} c_u \\
\frac{\partial (M_u q_u)}{\partial z} 
    &= E_u \overline{q} - D_u q_u  - \overline{\rho} c_u \\
\frac{\partial (M_u l)}{\partial z} 
    &= - D_u l + \overline{\rho} c_u - \overline{\rho} G_p 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No problem! Please remember to close this question. Happy TeXing!

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of reformatting the `align` environment solution to remove the final double-backslash to generate more-natural line breaks in the code. Feel free to revert.