# How to break the long equation when they wrap by a bracket?

Tags: equations

This is the equation:

```
\begin{equation}
U^*=\arg \underset{U}{\max } \sum _{m=1}^M  \omega _m \left[\ln \left(P_{\Lambda _m} (X(U,m)|C)\right)- \omega _{\text{KLD}} D_{\Lambda_m}\left(C(U),C\right)\right]
\end{equation}
```

I try to use `split` but it has error:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
U^*=\arg \underset{U}{\max } \sum _{m=1}^M  & \omega _m \left[\ln \left(P_{\Lambda _m} (X(U,m)|C)\right)- \\
 &\quad \omega _{\text{KLD}} D_{\Lambda_m}\left(C(U),C\right)\right]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

I follow [How to break a long equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8936/how-to-break-a-long-equation), but it seems not work for me.

How to make it effect?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21290/15925

Comment: This works for me.                                 
   \begin{equation}\label{eq1}
\begin{split}
U^*=\arg \underset{U}{\max } \sum _{m=1}^M & \omega _m \left[\ln \left(P_{\Lambda _m} (X(U,m)|C)\right)- \right. \\
& \left. {} \omega _{\text{KLD}} D_{\Lambda_m}\left(C(U),C\right)\vphantom{\ln}\right]
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: Yes, that works but you have to manually choose the right vphantom(s).