# How to fix, the equation from going off the page

Tags: equations, alignment, page

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
A^{j_1, j_2 , ... , j_p}_{k_1, k_2, ... , k_s, l} =  \frac{\partial{A^{j_1, j_2 , ... , j_p}_{k_1, k_2, ... , k_s}}}{\partial{{x}}^{l}} + \Gamma^{j_1}_{m l} A^{m (j_1, j_2 , ... , j_p)}_{(k_1, k_2, ... , k_s)} + \Gamma^{j_2}_{m l} A^{j_1 m (j_1, j_2 , ... , j_p)}_{(k_1, k_2, ... , k_s)}  +     ...     + \Gamma^{j_p}_{m l} A^{(j_1, j_2 , ... , j_{p-1})m}_{(k_1, k_2, ... , k_s)} - \Gamma^{m}_{k_1 l} A^{j_1, j_2 , ... , j_p}_{m (k_1, k_2, ... , k_s)} -  \Gamma^{m}_{k_2 l} A^{j_1, j_2 , ... , j_p}_{k_1 m (k_1, k_2, ... , k_s)} - ... -  \Gamma^{m}_{k_s l} A^{j_1, j_2 , ... , j_p}_{ (k_1, k_2, ... , k_{s-1})m}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to TeX.SX. Are the answers to this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8938/90297 helpful?

Comment: Remember there is no automatic line breaking in displayed math. You need to add the line breaks your self (`equation` does not support line breaks, but you can wrap your formula (inside `equation`) within `aligned` which does support line breaks)

Answer (score 2):

There are no automatic line breaking in displayed math. Here is how I'd break it. I also replaced `...` with the proper `\dots` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    A^{j_1, j_2 , \dots , j_p}_{k_1, k_2, \dots , k_s, l} = {} &
    \frac{\partial{A^{j_1, j_2 , \dots , j_p}_{k_1, k_2, \dots ,
          k_s}}}{\partial{{x}}^{l}} + \Gamma^{j_1}_{m l} A^{m (j_1,
      j_2 , \dots , j_p)}_{(k_1, k_2, \dots , k_s)}
    + \Gamma^{j_2}_{m
      l} A^{j_1 m (j_1, j_2 , \dots , j_p)}_{(k_1, k_2, \dots , k_s)}
    \\
    &+ \dots  + \Gamma^{j_p}_{m l} A^{(j_1, j_2 , \dots ,
      j_{p-1})m}_{(k_1, k_2, \dots , k_s)}
    - \Gamma^{m}_{k_1 l}
    A^{j_1, j_2 , \dots , j_p}_{m (k_1, k_2, \dots , k_s)}
    \\
    &  -\Gamma^{m}_{k_2 l} A^{j_1, j_2 , \dots , j_p}_{k_1 m (k_1, k_2,
      \dots , k_s)} - \dots - \Gamma^{m}_{k_s l} A^{j_1, j_2 , \dots ,
      j_p}_{ (k_1, k_2, \dots , k_{s-1})m}
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```