# Automatic page break for very long equations

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, line-breaking, breqn

I have ultra-long equation. I tried to use the `dmath` but got the error "Overfull \hbox" and it is not running in my main code. I even tried to change `\left(` and `\right)` to `\biggl(` and `\biggr)` but still not working. I can use `multline` but manually keeping the line breaks `\\` in so long equation for hundreds of lines is not possible. Kindly suggest a way to handle this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\begin{dmath}
\lambda _3+\frac{1}{\biggl(a+4 b+p\biggr)^9}2\biggl(-1048576 x_3 k12{}^2 b^{10}-1572864 a x_3 k12{}^2b^9-2359296 p x_3 k12{}^2 b^9+262144 p \epsilon21 k12 b^9-884736 a^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^8-2359296 p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^8-3080192 a p x_3 k12{}^2 b^8+589824 p^2 \epsilon21 k12 b^8+458752 a p \epsilon21 k12 b^8-163840 a^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^7-1376256 p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^7-2621440 a p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^7-1572864 a^2 d x_3 k12{}^2 b^7-1417216 a^2 p x_3 k12{}^2 b^7+589824 p^3 \epsilon21 k12 b^7+917504 a p^2 \epsilon21 k12 b^7+344064 a^2 p \epsilon21 k12 b^7+55296 a^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b^6-516096 p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b^6-1261568 a p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^6-931840 a^2 p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^6-1310720 a^3 d x_3 k12{}^2 b^6+1310720 a^3 e x_3 k12{}^2 b^6-131072 a^3 p x_3 k12{}^2 b^6-2752512 a^2 d p x_3 k12{}^2 b^6+344064 p^4 \epsilon21 k12 b^6+802816 a p^3 \epsilon21 k12 b^6+602112 a^2 p^2 \epsilon21 k12 b^6+143360 a^3 p \epsilon21 k12 b^6+39936 a^5 x_3 k12{}^2 b^5-372736 a p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b^5-311808 a^2 p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^5+18432 a^3 p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^5-2064384 a^2 d p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^5-434176 a^4 d x_3 k12{}^2 b^5+573440 a^4 e x_3 k12{}^2 b^5+126464 a^4 p x_3 k12{}^2 b^5-1966080 a^3 d p x_3 k12{}^2 b^5+1966080 a^3 e p x_3 k12{}^2 b^5+129024 p^5 \epsilon21 k12 b^5+401408 a p^4 \epsilon21 k12 b^5+451584 a^2 p^3 \epsilon21 k12 b^5+215040 a^3 p^2 \epsilon21 k12 b^5+35840 a^4 p \epsilon21 k12 b^5+10624 a^6 x_3 k12{}^2 b^4-49280 a^2 p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b^4+56320 a^3 p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^4-860160 a^2 d p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^4+106240 a^4 p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^4-1228800 a^3 d p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^4+1228800 a^3 e p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^4-75776 a^5 d x_3 k12{}^2 b^4+102400 a^5 e x_3 k12{}^2 b^4+57856 a^5 p x_3 k12{}^2 b^4-542720 a^4 d p x_3 k12{}^2 b^4+716800 a^4 e p x_3 k12{}^2 b^4+32256 p^6 \epsilon21 k12 b^4+125440 a p^5 \epsilon21 k12 b^4+188160 a^2 p^4 \epsilon21 k12 b^4+134400 a^3 p^3 \epsilon21 k12 b^4+44800 a^4 p^2 \epsilon21 k12 b^4+5376 a^5 p \epsilon21 k12 b^4+1536 a^7 x_3 k12{}^2 b^3+26240 a^3 p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b^3-215040 a^2 d p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b^3+44480 a^4 p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^3-409600 a^3 d p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^3+409600 a^3 e p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^3+32896 a^5 p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^3-271360 a^4 d p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^3+358400 a^4 e p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^3-7936 a^6 d x_3 k12{}^2 b^3+10240 a^6 e x_3 k12{}^2 b^3+11552 a^6 p x_3 k12{}^2 b^3-75776 a^5 d p x_3 k12{}^2 b^3+102400 a^5 e p x_3 k12{}^2 b^3+5376 p^7 \epsilon21 k12 b^3+25088 a p^6 \epsilon21 k12 b^3+47040 a^2 p^5 \epsilon21 k12 b^3+44800 a^3 p^4 \epsilon21 k12 b^3+22400 a^4 p^3 \epsilon21 k12 b^3+5376 a^5 p^2 \epsilon21 k12 b^3+448 a^6 p \epsilon21 k12 b^3+120 a^8 x_3 k12{}^2 b^2+10040 a^4 p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b^2-76800 a^3 d p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b^2+9216 a^5 p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^2-67840 a^4 d p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^2+89600 a^4 e p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^2+4680 a^6 p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^2-28416 a^5 d p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^2+38400 a^5 e p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^2-512 a^7 d x_3 k12{}^2 b^2+640 a^7 e x_3 k12{}^2 b^2+1216 a^7 p x_3 k12{}^2 b^2-5952 a^6 d p x_3 k12{}^2 b^2+7680 a^6 e p x_3 k12{}^2 b^2+576 p^8 \epsilon21 k12 b^2+3136 a p^7 \epsilon21 k12 b^2+7056 a^2 p^6 \epsilon21 k12 b^2+8400 a^3 p^5 \epsilon21 k12 b^2+5600 a^4 p^4 \epsilon21 k12 b^2+2016 a^5 p^3 \epsilon21 k12 b^2+336 a^6 p^2 \epsilon21 k12 b^2+16 a^7 p \epsilon21 k12 b^2+4 a^9 x_3 k12{}^2 b+1276 a^5 p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b-8480 a^4 d p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b+11200 a^4 e p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b+838 a^6 p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b-4736 a^5 d p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b+6400 a^5 e p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b+320 a^7 p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b-1488 a^6 d p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b+1920 a^6 e p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b-16 a^8 d x_3 k12{}^2 b+20 a^8 e x_3 k12{}^2 b+62 a^8 p x_3 k12{}^2 b-256 a^7 d p x_3 k12{}^2 b+320 a^7 e p x_3 k12{}^2 b+36 p^9 \epsilon21 k12 b+224 a p^8 \epsilon21 k12 b+588 a^2 p^7 \epsilon21 k12 b+840 a^3 p^6 \epsilon21 k12 b+700 a^4 p^5 \epsilon21 k12 b+336 a^5 p^4 \epsilon21 k12 b+84 a^6 p^3 \epsilon21 k12 b+8 a^7 p^2 \epsilon21 k12 b+\biggl(4 b+p\biggr) \biggl(a^9+\biggl(34 b+20 d-35 e+8 p\biggr) a^8+8 \biggl(4 b+p\biggr) \biggl(17 b+26 d-45 e+4 p\biggr) a^7+\biggl(4 b+p\biggr)^2 \biggl(322 b+860 d-1520 e+83 p\biggr) a^6+4 \biggl(4 b+p\biggr)^3 \biggl(119 b+406 d-700 e+37 p\biggr) a^5+\biggl(4 b+p\biggr)^4 \biggl(434 b+1304 d-1680 e+181 p\biggr) a^4+4 \biggl(4 b+p\biggr)^5 \biggl(56 b+64 d+80 e+37 p\biggr) a^3+\biggl(4 b+p\biggr)^6 \biggl(46 b-96 d+77 p\biggr) a^2-\biggl(8 b-23 p\biggr) \biggl(4 b+p\biggr)^7 a-\biggl(4 b-3 p\biggr) \biggl(4 b+p\biggr)^8\biggr) x_3 k11{}^2+56 a^6 p^4 x_3 k12{}^2-296 a^5 d p^4 x_3 k12{}^2+400 a^5 e p^4 x_3 k12{}^2+28 a^7 p^3 x_3 k12{}^2-124 a^6 d p^3 x_3 k12{}^2+160 a^6 e p^3 x_3 k12{}^2+8 a^8 p^2 x_3 k12{}^2-32 a^7 d p^2 x_3 k12{}^2+40 a^7 e p^2 x_3 k12{}^2+a^9 p x_3 k12{}^2\biggl)=0
\end{dmath}
\end{document}
```

Comment: External link often breaks after some time. Include in the question the  minimal working example, but with a not so ultra-long equation, but just one long enough to show the problem.  Anyway, this seem a duplicate of  [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8936/how-to-break-a-long-equation) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/how-can-i-split-an-equation-over-two-or-more-lines)  question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I split an equation over two (or more) lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/how-can-i-split-an-equation-over-two-or-more-lines)

Comment: As this question is about automatic (and not manual) linebreaks, the linked questions don't seem to answer it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Desciption

Page breaks are automatically added if you use a normal math environment (or $...$).

I added an equation number manually using the default`equation` counter.

Note: `\biggl(` and `\biggr)` aren't of any use, if you replace all brackets by them. Then you could just use normal `()`.

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\begin{math}
\lambda _3+\frac{1}{\biggl(a+4 b+p\biggr)^9}2\biggl(-1048576 x_3 k12{}^2 b^{10}-1572864 a x_3 k12{}^2b^9-2359296 p x_3 k12{}^2 b^9+262144 p \epsilon21 k12 b^9-884736 a^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^8-2359296 p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^8-3080192 a p x_3 k12{}^2 b^8+589824 p^2 \epsilon21 k12 b^8+458752 a p \epsilon21 k12 b^8-163840 a^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^7-1376256 p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^7-2621440 a p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^7-1572864 a^2 d x_3 k12{}^2 b^7-1417216 a^2 p x_3 k12{}^2 b^7+589824 p^3 \epsilon21 k12 b^7+917504 a p^2 \epsilon21 k12 b^7+344064 a^2 p \epsilon21 k12 b^7+55296 a^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b^6-516096 p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b^6-1261568 a p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^6-931840 a^2 p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^6-1310720 a^3 d x_3 k12{}^2 b^6+1310720 a^3 e x_3 k12{}^2 b^6-131072 a^3 p x_3 k12{}^2 b^6-2752512 a^2 d p x_3 k12{}^2 b^6+344064 p^4 \epsilon21 k12 b^6+802816 a p^3 \epsilon21 k12 b^6+602112 a^2 p^2 \epsilon21 k12 b^6+143360 a^3 p \epsilon21 k12 b^6+39936 a^5 x_3 k12{}^2 b^5-372736 a p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b^5-311808 a^2 p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^5+18432 a^3 p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^5-2064384 a^2 d p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^5-434176 a^4 d x_3 k12{}^2 b^5+573440 a^4 e x_3 k12{}^2 b^5+126464 a^4 p x_3 k12{}^2 b^5-1966080 a^3 d p x_3 k12{}^2 b^5+1966080 a^3 e p x_3 k12{}^2 b^5+129024 p^5 \epsilon21 k12 b^5+401408 a p^4 \epsilon21 k12 b^5+451584 a^2 p^3 \epsilon21 k12 b^5+215040 a^3 p^2 \epsilon21 k12 b^5+35840 a^4 p \epsilon21 k12 b^5+10624 a^6 x_3 k12{}^2 b^4-49280 a^2 p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b^4+56320 a^3 p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^4-860160 a^2 d p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^4+106240 a^4 p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^4-1228800 a^3 d p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^4+1228800 a^3 e p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^4-75776 a^5 d x_3 k12{}^2 b^4+102400 a^5 e x_3 k12{}^2 b^4+57856 a^5 p x_3 k12{}^2 b^4-542720 a^4 d p x_3 k12{}^2 b^4+716800 a^4 e p x_3 k12{}^2 b^4+32256 p^6 \epsilon21 k12 b^4+125440 a p^5 \epsilon21 k12 b^4+188160 a^2 p^4 \epsilon21 k12 b^4+134400 a^3 p^3 \epsilon21 k12 b^4+44800 a^4 p^2 \epsilon21 k12 b^4+5376 a^5 p \epsilon21 k12 b^4+1536 a^7 x_3 k12{}^2 b^3+26240 a^3 p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b^3-215040 a^2 d p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b^3+44480 a^4 p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^3-409600 a^3 d p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^3+409600 a^3 e p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^3+32896 a^5 p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^3-271360 a^4 d p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^3+358400 a^4 e p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^3-7936 a^6 d x_3 k12{}^2 b^3+10240 a^6 e x_3 k12{}^2 b^3+11552 a^6 p x_3 k12{}^2 b^3-75776 a^5 d p x_3 k12{}^2 b^3+102400 a^5 e p x_3 k12{}^2 b^3+5376 p^7 \epsilon21 k12 b^3+25088 a p^6 \epsilon21 k12 b^3+47040 a^2 p^5 \epsilon21 k12 b^3+44800 a^3 p^4 \epsilon21 k12 b^3+22400 a^4 p^3 \epsilon21 k12 b^3+5376 a^5 p^2 \epsilon21 k12 b^3+448 a^6 p \epsilon21 k12 b^3+120 a^8 x_3 k12{}^2 b^2+10040 a^4 p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b^2-76800 a^3 d p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b^2+9216 a^5 p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^2-67840 a^4 d p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^2+89600 a^4 e p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^2+4680 a^6 p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^2-28416 a^5 d p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^2+38400 a^5 e p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^2-512 a^7 d x_3 k12{}^2 b^2+640 a^7 e x_3 k12{}^2 b^2+1216 a^7 p x_3 k12{}^2 b^2-5952 a^6 d p x_3 k12{}^2 b^2+7680 a^6 e p x_3 k12{}^2 b^2+576 p^8 \epsilon21 k12 b^2+3136 a p^7 \epsilon21 k12 b^2+7056 a^2 p^6 \epsilon21 k12 b^2+8400 a^3 p^5 \epsilon21 k12 b^2+5600 a^4 p^4 \epsilon21 k12 b^2+2016 a^5 p^3 \epsilon21 k12 b^2+336 a^6 p^2 \epsilon21 k12 b^2+16 a^7 p \epsilon21 k12 b^2+4 a^9 x_3 k12{}^2 b+1276 a^5 p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b-8480 a^4 d p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b+11200 a^4 e p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b+838 a^6 p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b-4736 a^5 d p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b+6400 a^5 e p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b+320 a^7 p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b-1488 a^6 d p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b+1920 a^6 e p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b-16 a^8 d x_3 k12{}^2 b+20 a^8 e x_3 k12{}^2 b+62 a^8 p x_3 k12{}^2 b-256 a^7 d p x_3 k12{}^2 b+320 a^7 e p x_3 k12{}^2 b+36 p^9 \epsilon21 k12 b+224 a p^8 \epsilon21 k12 b+588 a^2 p^7 \epsilon21 k12 b+840 a^3 p^6 \epsilon21 k12 b+700 a^4 p^5 \epsilon21 k12 b+336 a^5 p^4 \epsilon21 k12 b+84 a^6 p^3 \epsilon21 k12 b+8 a^7 p^2 \epsilon21 k12 b+\biggl(4 b+p\biggr) \biggl(a^9+\biggl(34 b+20 d-35 e+8 p\biggr) a^8+8 \biggl(4 b+p\biggr) \biggl(17 b+26 d-45 e+4 p\biggr) a^7+\biggl(4 b+p\biggr)^2 \biggl(322 b+860 d-1520 e+83 p\biggr) a^6+4 \biggl(4 b+p\biggr)^3 \biggl(119 b+406 d-700 e+37 p\biggr) a^5+\biggl(4 b+p\biggr)^4 \biggl(434 b+1304 d-1680 e+181 p\biggr) a^4+4 \biggl(4 b+p\biggr)^5 \biggl(56 b+64 d+80 e+37 p\biggr) a^3+\biggl(4 b+p\biggr)^6 \biggl(46 b-96 d+77 p\biggr) a^2-\biggl(8 b-23 p\biggr) \biggl(4 b+p\biggr)^7 a-\biggl(4 b-3 p\biggr) \biggl(4 b+p\biggr)^8\biggr) x_3 k11{}^2+56 a^6 p^4 x_3 k12{}^2-296 a^5 d p^4 x_3 k12{}^2+400 a^5 e p^4 x_3 k12{}^2+28 a^7 p^3 x_3 k12{}^2-124 a^6 d p^3 x_3 k12{}^2+160 a^6 e p^3 x_3 k12{}^2+8 a^8 p^2 x_3 k12{}^2-32 a^7 d p^2 x_3 k12{}^2+40 a^7 e p^2 x_3 k12{}^2+a^9 p x_3 k12{}^2\biggl)=0
\hfill
\refstepcounter{equation}
(\theequation)
\label{eq:myequation}
\end{math}

See (\ref{eq:myequation}).

\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: But this equation is not numbered. How to number it?

Comment: @S.B.MD.KhajaMoinuddin I added an equation number manually.

Comment: Have you tried to `\ref` the equation? `;-)`

Comment: @campa hm, apparently not. Do you have a suggestion for that?

Comment: Jokes aside, for `\label` to work you should use `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter`. `\label` always refers to the last counter increased by `\refstepcounter`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I made an edit.

Answer (score 1):

With not big manual intervention:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begingroup
\rightskip=10em minus 10em
\binoppenalty=0
\parfillskip=-\rightskip
$\lambda _3+\frac{1}{(a+4 b+p)^9}2\Bigl(-1048576 x_3 k12{}^2 b^{10}-1572864 a x_3 k12{}^2b^9-2359296 p x_3 k12{}^2 b^9+262144 p \epsilon21 k12 b^9-884736 a^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^8-2359296 p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^8-3080192 a p x_3 k12{}^2 b^8+589824 p^2 \epsilon21 k12 b^8+458752 a p \epsilon21 k12 b^8-163840 a^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^7-1376256 p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^7-2621440 a p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^7-1572864 a^2 d x_3 k12{}^2 b^7-1417216 a^2 p x_3 k12{}^2 b^7+589824 p^3 \epsilon21 k12 b^7+917504 a p^2 \epsilon21 k12 b^7+344064 a^2 p \epsilon21 k12 b^7+55296 a^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b^6-516096 p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b^6-1261568 a p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^6-931840 a^2 p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^6-1310720 a^3 d x_3 k12{}^2 b^6+1310720 a^3 e x_3 k12{}^2 b^6-131072 a^3 p x_3 k12{}^2 b^6-2752512 a^2 d p x_3 k12{}^2 b^6+344064 p^4 \epsilon21 k12 b^6+802816 a p^3 \epsilon21 k12 b^6+602112 a^2 p^2 \epsilon21 k12 b^6+143360 a^3 p \epsilon21 k12 b^6+39936 a^5 x_3 k12{}^2 b^5-372736 a p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b^5-311808 a^2 p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^5+18432 a^3 p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^5-2064384 a^2 d p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^5-434176 a^4 d x_3 k12{}^2 b^5+573440 a^4 e x_3 k12{}^2 b^5+126464 a^4 p x_3 k12{}^2 b^5-1966080 a^3 d p x_3 k12{}^2 b^5+1966080 a^3 e p x_3 k12{}^2 b^5+129024 p^5 \epsilon21 k12 b^5+401408 a p^4 \epsilon21 k12 b^5+451584 a^2 p^3 \epsilon21 k12 b^5+215040 a^3 p^2 \epsilon21 k12 b^5+35840 a^4 p \epsilon21 k12 b^5+10624 a^6 x_3 k12{}^2 b^4-49280 a^2 p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b^4+56320 a^3 p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^4-860160 a^2 d p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^4+106240 a^4 p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^4-1228800 a^3 d p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^4+1228800 a^3 e p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^4-75776 a^5 d x_3 k12{}^2 b^4+102400 a^5 e x_3 k12{}^2 b^4+57856 a^5 p x_3 k12{}^2 b^4-542720 a^4 d p x_3 k12{}^2 b^4+716800 a^4 e p x_3 k12{}^2 b^4+32256 p^6 \epsilon21 k12 b^4+125440 a p^5 \epsilon21 k12 b^4+188160 a^2 p^4 \epsilon21 k12 b^4+134400 a^3 p^3 \epsilon21 k12 b^4+44800 a^4 p^2 \epsilon21 k12 b^4+5376 a^5 p \epsilon21 k12 b^4+1536 a^7 x_3 k12{}^2 b^3+26240 a^3 p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b^3-215040 a^2 d p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b^3+44480 a^4 p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^3-409600 a^3 d p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^3+409600 a^3 e p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^3+32896 a^5 p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^3-271360 a^4 d p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^3+358400 a^4 e p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^3-7936 a^6 d x_3 k12{}^2 b^3+10240 a^6 e x_3 k12{}^2 b^3+11552 a^6 p x_3 k12{}^2 b^3-75776 a^5 d p x_3 k12{}^2 b^3+102400 a^5 e p x_3 k12{}^2 b^3+5376 p^7 \epsilon21 k12 b^3+25088 a p^6 \epsilon21 k12 b^3+47040 a^2 p^5 \epsilon21 k12 b^3+44800 a^3 p^4 \epsilon21 k12 b^3+22400 a^4 p^3 \epsilon21 k12 b^3+5376 a^5 p^2 \epsilon21 k12 b^3+448 a^6 p \epsilon21 k12 b^3+120 a^8 x_3 k12{}^2 b^2+10040 a^4 p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b^2-76800 a^3 d p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b^2+9216 a^5 p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^2-67840 a^4 d p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^2+89600 a^4 e p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b^2+4680 a^6 p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^2-28416 a^5 d p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^2+38400 a^5 e p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b^2-512 a^7 d x_3 k12{}^2 b^2+640 a^7 e x_3 k12{}^2 b^2+1216 a^7 p x_3 k12{}^2 b^2-5952 a^6 d p x_3 k12{}^2 b^2+7680 a^6 e p x_3 k12{}^2 b^2+576 p^8 \epsilon21 k12 b^2+3136 a p^7 \epsilon21 k12 b^2+7056 a^2 p^6 \epsilon21 k12 b^2+8400 a^3 p^5 \epsilon21 k12 b^2+5600 a^4 p^4 \epsilon21 k12 b^2+2016 a^5 p^3 \epsilon21 k12 b^2+336 a^6 p^2 \epsilon21 k12 b^2+16 a^7 p \epsilon21 k12 b^2+4 a^9 x_3 k12{}^2 b+1276 a^5 p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b-8480 a^4 d p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b+11200 a^4 e p^4 x_3 k12{}^2 b+838 a^6 p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b-4736 a^5 d p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b+6400 a^5 e p^3 x_3 k12{}^2 b+320 a^7 p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b-1488 a^6 d p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b+1920 a^6 e p^2 x_3 k12{}^2 b-16 a^8 d x_3 k12{}^2 b+20 a^8 e x_3 k12{}^2 b+62 a^8 p x_3 k12{}^2 b-256 a^7 d p x_3 k12{}^2 b+320 a^7 e p x_3 k12{}^2 b+36 p^9 \epsilon21 k12 b+224 a p^8 \epsilon21 k12 b+588 a^2 p^7 \epsilon21 k12 b+840 a^3 p^6 \epsilon21 k12 b+700 a^4 p^5 \epsilon21 k12 b+336 a^5 p^4 \epsilon21 k12 b+84 a^6 p^3 \epsilon21 k12 b+8 a^7 p^2 \epsilon21 k12 b+\left(4 b+p\right) \bigl(a^9+\left(34 b+20 d-35 e+8 p\right) a^8+8 \left(4 b+p\right) \left(17 b+26 d-45 e+4 p\right) a^7+\left(4 b+p\right)^2 \left(322 b+860 d-1520 e+83 p\right) a^6+4 \left(4 b+p\right)^3 \left(119 b+406 d-700 e+37 p\right) a^5+\hfil\break \left(4 b+p\right)^4 \left(434 b+1304 d-1680 e+181 p\right) a^4+\hfil\break 4 \left(4 b+p\right)^5 \left(56 b+64 d+80 e+37 p\right) a^3+\left(4 b+p\right)^6 \left(46 b-96 d+77 p\right) a^2-\left(8 b-23 p\right) \left(4 b+p\right)^7 a-\left(4 b-3 p\right) \left(4 b+p\right)^8\bigr) x_3 k11{}^2+56 a^6 p^4 x_3 k12{}^2-296 a^5 d p^4 x_3 k12{}^2+400 a^5 e p^4 x_3 k12{}^2+28 a^7 p^3 x_3 k12{}^2-124 a^6 d p^3 x_3 k12{}^2+160 a^6 e p^3 x_3 k12{}^2+8 a^8 p^2 x_3 k12{}^2-32 a^7 d p^2 x_3 k12{}^2+40 a^7 e p^2 x_3 k12{}^2+a^9 p x_3 k12{}^2\Bigr)=0$
\unskip\nobreak\hfill\stepcounter{equation}(\theequation)\par
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\left(...\right)` bits keep parenthesized parts together. A couple of `\hfil\break` have to be manually inserted.

Comment: Wouldn't `\refstepcounter` be better?