# Centering split equation

Tags: math-mode, formatting, equations, amsmath

I am quite new to TeX. I want that each line in the following equation be centered, but I cannot find how to do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a & = \frac{M_{20}}{M_{00}} - x^{2}_{c}, \;\;\;
b = 2(\frac{M_{11}}{M_{00}} - x_{c}y_{c}), \;\;\;
c = \frac{M_{02}}{M_{00}} - y^{2}_{c}, \\
&\quad x_{c} = \frac{M_{10}}{M_{00}}, \;\;\;
y_{c} = \frac{M_{01}}{M_{00}}, \\
&\quad M_{ij} = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{x} \displaystyle\sum\limits_{y} x^i y^j I(x,y)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Also, it would be awesome if I could write "and" after the first line ;)

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's always best to have compilable code.

Comment: Check out Philipp's answer. Embedding of `gathered` in `equation` puts one _centered_ equation number nexts to centered equations. The accepted answer forces the equation number onto the last line and a large number of `\notag` commands.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
a  = \frac{M_{20}}{M_{00}} - x^{2}_{c},\quad
b = 2(\frac{M_{11}}{M_{00}} - x_{c}y_{c}),\quad
c = \frac{M_{02}}{M_{00}} - y^{2}_{c},\nonumber\\[1ex]
\text{and}\nonumber\\[1ex]
x_{c} = \frac{M_{10}}{M_{00}},\quad
y_{c} = \frac{M_{01}}{M_{00}}, \nonumber\\
M_{ij} = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{x} \displaystyle\sum\limits_{y} x^i y^j I(x,y)
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of `\displaystyle\sum\limits_{x}` you can write `\sum_{x}`

Comment: or `\sum_x`... :-)

Comment: I used '\displaystyle\sum\limits_{x}' since the position of limit is a little bit different from '\sum_{x}'. With '\displaystyle\sum\limits_{x}' it actually goes below '\sum'.

Comment: Inside an equation environment  it is already at displaystyle, and the subscript will be placed below. amsmath also defined the \intertext{} command which is made for exactly for inserting a short text between equations like this.

Answer (score 38):

Just replace the `split` environment by `gathered`, then you don't have to suppress spurious equation numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
a = \frac{M_{20}}{M_{00}} - x^{2}_{c}, \;\;\;
b = 2(\frac{M_{11}}{M_{00}} - x_{c}y_{c}), \;\;\;
c = \frac{M_{02}}{M_{00}} - y^{2}_{c}, \\
\quad x_{c} = \frac{M_{10}}{M_{00}}, \;\;\;
y_{c} = \frac{M_{01}}{M_{00}}, \\
\quad M_{ij} = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{x} \displaystyle\sum\limits_{y} x^i y^j I(x,y)
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This should be definitely the right answer...

Comment: @GiuTeX why?  Is it significantly different from the accepted answer?

Comment: @Nathan gotta be honest with you I don't remember at all why I wrote that. Looking now at the accepted answer I can't say there are substantial differences...

Comment: @GiuTeX other voters seem to agree with you, though.  I suppose the abstracting-away of other subtleties and just leaving the votes to speak probably mean you're right

Answer (score 4):

The code below is not exactly what you asked for, but it has some alternatives that you might want consider.

- Use `\left` and `\right` to fix the size of the parenthesis
- Use `\intertext` to put words between equations
- Use `&` to get better control of alignment

You mentioned you are new. You might want to read the [mathtools document](ftp://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mh/mathtools.pdf).

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
a &= \frac {M_{20} } {M_{00} } - x^{2}_{c} , &
b &= 2 \left (  \frac {M_{11} } {M_{00} } - x_{c} y_{c}  \right )  , & %NOTE THE \LEFT AND \RIGHT
c &= \frac {M_{02} } {M_{00} } - y^{2}_{c} , \\
\intertext {and} % NOTE THE 'CORRECT' USAGE OF INTERTEXT TO WRITE IN BETWEEN EQUATIONS
&& \quad x_{c} &= \frac {M_{10} } {M_{00} } , & % NOTE THE DOUBLE && TO ALIGN TO THE SECOND COLUMN
y_{c} &= \frac {M_{01} } {M_{00} } , \\
\intertext {Some text}
&& \quad M_{ij} &= \sum \limits_{x} \sum \limits_{y} x^i y^j I( x, y )
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{amsmath}   
\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
a = \frac{M_{20}}{M_{00}} - x^{2}_{c}, \;\;\; 
    b = 2\left(\frac{M_{11}}{M_{00}} - x_{c}y_{c}\right), \;\;\;
    c = \frac{M_{02}}{M_{00}} - y^{2}_{c}, \nonumber\\
x_{c} = \frac{M_{10}}{M_{00}}, \;\;\; y_{c} = \frac{M_{01}}{M_{00}}, \\
M_{ij} = \sum_x\sum_y x^i y^j I(x,y)\nonumber
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```