# How to center a multiline equation?

Tags: equations, knitr, pandoc

I want to center multi row equationing but all my attemts won't work. I'm working with pandoc/knitr of Rmarkdown. I show you an example:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
<!-- \begin{center} -->
\label{eq1}
x_1 = 1, x_2 = 1 \\
h(x) = f(-20 + 15 + 17) \\
h(x) = f(12) \approx 1 \\
<!-- \end{center} -->
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

When I use center, I get this error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
            $
l.100 \begin{center}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `center` is a text-mode environment. Don't use it inside math mode. (The material inside a `center` env. is taken to be text-mode material by default.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use a `gathered` environment inside the `equation` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "gathered" env.
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
  \begin{gathered}
    x_1 = 1,\ x_2 = 1       \\
    h(x) = f(-20 + 15 + 17) \\
    h(x) = f(12) \approx 1   % no "\\" needed here
  \end{gathered}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I vote your question Mico. JaySf, there is a similar question at the link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9268/centering-split-equation.

Comment: See, in particular, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9278/5001) to the query identified by @Sebastiano.

Comment: @Mico How do to create a direct link of the answer (see **this answer**), please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Sebastiano - Instead of writing `<url>`, write `[this answer](<url>)`. (It's an example of "markdown code".)

Comment: @MIco Thanksssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss. Great!!!