# How do I put a linebreak in a displaymath?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I split an equation over two lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/how-can-i-split-an-equation-over-two-lines)

I have a `displaymath` formula that's too long. `\linebreak` and other commands that work in inline math don't seem to do anything. Is there any way to break the `displaymath` onto multiple lines? (or preferably, have latex break it automatically?)

I saw some other related questions here at tex.stackexchange, which said "use `align`/`eqnarray*`/etc instead". My formula doesn't need breaking for layout reasons, just because it's too long, so I'd prefer to keep using `displaymath`. Is there a way to linebreak *without* changing environments?

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I split an equation over two lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3782/2693)

Comment: I recommend not insisting on using the single-line math environment `displaymath` for multiple lines. amsmath offers simple multi line environments such as `multline` and `gather` but also more sophisticated.