# Dividing an equation into two lines

Tags: equations

I am trying to divide this equation into two different lines but I am not able to. I tried to use package [`breqn`](http://ctan.org/pkg/breqn) but that started giving me some compilation errors on the style file itself.

```
\frac{ \sum_{n_i\in S_{c_k}} P_{ij} ( x_{i} P(y_i = 1\ |\ x_i = 1) + (1- x_{i}) P (y_i = 1\ |\ x_i=0))}{\sum_{n_i\in S_{c_k}} P_{ij}}
```

The problem here is `\frac{}` which prevents me from using `align` to break the equation.

[image]

Comment: The equation itself fits on a single line. Where do you want to break it?

Comment: There seem to be more `}` right braces than `{` left braces in that equation. Are there?

Comment: The start of that equation looks a little ... odd.  Do you *really* want the `P` on the denominator of the fraction with the subscript `i` removed from it?  Or did you want `P_i` there?  It's unusual notation to have an empty summation divided by something.

Comment: Well, the original equation was somewhat longer. I removed some useless parts from it to simplify it. Now it does fit in a line and looks odd.

Comment: The input and the output don't agree. Anyway, it's impossible to break a fraction across lines.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I split an equation over two lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/how-can-i-split-an-equation-over-two-lines)

Answer (score 7):

You can use  **multline**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
a+b+c+d+e+f\\
+i+j+k+l+m+n
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In the sake of minimality, you can omit `amssymb` ;) As well, some additional relevant information: (1) `multline*` supresses equation numbering; (2) it goes like this: first line is left-aligned, all middle lines are centered, last line is right-aligned.

Comment: amssymb removed

Comment: multiline does not seem to work with \frac. Latex complains about missing }

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention that this is a simplified version of your actual formula, I am assuming that it won't fit on one line. If so, here is one way you can display a similar equation over multiple lines:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sum_{n_i\in S_{c_k}} P_{ij}}
\Biggl[
\sum_{n_i\in S_{c_k}} &\phantom{+}P_{ij} \bigl( x_{i} P(y_i = 1\ |\  x_i = 1 ) \\
    &+ (1- x_{i}) P(y_i = 1\ |\ x_i=0)\bigr) \Biggr]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've fixed `\bigl` and similar ones. Probably `multline` is better, as it doesn't require finding alignment points.