# Auto-breaking of Equation

Tags: equations, line-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I split an equation over two lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/how-can-i-split-an-equation-over-two-lines)

I want to make my own class file having a two columns. I just want to ask if there's a possibility where we can automatically break the equation once exceeded in the margin.

Comment: [The `breqn` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/breqn) might help. Here are the question on this site: [`breqn` questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breqn)