# how to typeset a fraction with a very loooong expression in the denominator?

Tags: math-mode

I have problem, because I have long maths formula. So I would like have it in two lines. What I do:

```
P_{N_3}(P_X(t)) = \\ \frac{1.098848191 \cdot 10^{596}}{(-1.0 \cdot 10^{12}+8.33 \cdot 10^{9} \cdot t+7.50 \cdot 10^{10} \cdot t^2+4.167 \cdot 10^9 \cdot t^4+3.33 \cdot 10^{10} \cdot t^5+4.167 \cdot 10^{10} \cdot t^8+4.167 \cdot 10^9 \cdot t^{10})^50}
```

As you can see, after equal sign I have `\\` which unfortunately doesn't work. I use following packages:

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Why it doesn't work? Could you help me? I use Miktex and editor Texmaker. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which math environment are you using? `\[ ... \]`, `equation` for example does not allow for line breaks, while `align` and `gather` does.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! ``\\`` isn't supposed to work in a `equation` environment or in `\[...\]`. You load `amsmath`, so you want to look at `split` or `align`

Comment: Please always provide a _complete_ document not an unusable fragment. I would guess that you are in an `equation` environment, which is always one line. Use `amsmath` package `align` environment (or one of its variants) for multi-line equations.

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/how-can-i-split-an-equation-over-two-lines) thread should help.

Comment: Please note that the solution mentioned in the posting that @Chris has linked does *not* solve the OP's problem: In the current question, the linebreak has to occur in the denominator term of a fraction expression.

Comment: I've always been fond of "`\[\frac{...}{C}\] where \[C = ...\]`". This works particularly well when the long denominator `C` is really just a normalization constant that will cancel out later anyway.

Answer (score 13):

I think what you need is the `\splitfrac` macro provided by the [mathtools](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
P_{N_3}\bigl(P_X(t)\bigr) = 
\dfrac{1.098848191 \cdot 10^{596} }{
\splitfrac{\bigl(
-1.0 \cdot 10^{12}
+8.33 \cdot 10^{9} \cdot t
+7.50 \cdot 10^{10} \cdot t^2
+4.167 \cdot 10^9 \cdot t^4}{+3.33 \cdot 10^{10} \cdot t^5
+4.167 \cdot 10^{10} \cdot t^8
+4.167 \cdot 10^9 \cdot t^{10}
\bigr)^{50}} }
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: You could also choose not to use a `\frac` or `\dfrac` directive at all, and instead typeset the denominator encased in `[...]^{-50}`, use a `multline` environment (or its unnumbered version, `multline*`), and provide a suitably chosen `\\` to force a line break:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
P_{N_3}\bigl(P_X(t)\bigr) = 
1.098848191 \cdot 10^{596}\times\big[
-1.0 \cdot 10^{12} +8.33 \cdot 10^{9} \cdot t +7.50 \cdot 10^{10} \cdot t^2\\
+3.33 \cdot 10^{10} \cdot t^5 +4.167 \cdot 10^{10} \cdot t^8 +4.167 \cdot 10^9 \cdot t^{10} \big]^{-50}
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

I know it's not everybody's cup of tea but I find the matrix version always more readable if the polynomial is meant to be read.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\[
P_{N_3}\bigl(P_X(t)\bigr) = 
1.098848191 \cdot 10^{596} \left[\left(
\sisetup{table-format = +1.3e+2,exponent-product=\cdot}
\begin{tabular}{S}
-1.0e12   \\
 8.33e9   \\
 7.50e10  \\
 4.167e9  \\
 3.33e10  \\
 4.167e10 \\
 4.167e9 
\end{tabular}
\right)^{\!\!T}
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ t\\ t^2\\t^4 \\t^5\\t^8\\t^{10}
\end{pmatrix}\right]^{-50}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just another way to present the formula:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  P_{N_3}\bigl(P_X(t)\bigr) & = (1.098848191 \cdot 10^{596})              \\
                            & \qquad                                      
  \begin{aligned}
    \times \bigl(           & -1.0 \cdot 10^{12}                          \\
                            & +8.33 \cdot 10^{9} \cdot t                  \\
                            & +7.50 \cdot 10^{10} \cdot t^2               \\
                            & +4.167 \cdot 10^9 \cdot t^4                 \\
                            & +3.33 \cdot 10^{10} \cdot t^5               \\
                            & +4.167 \cdot 10^{10} \cdot t^8              \\
                            & +4.167 \cdot 10^9 \cdot t^{10} \bigr)^{-50} 
  \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the paragraph, or simplify the fraction or both:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Let us write
\[ P_{N_3}(P_X(t)) = \frac{A}{Q(t)^{50}}\]
where
\[ Q(t) = a_0 + a_1 t + a_2 t^2 + a_3 t^3 + a_4 t^4
    + a_5 t^5 + a_8 t^8 + a_{10} t^{10} \]
and
\begin{align*}
    A &= 1.098848191 \cdot 10^{596}\\
  a_0 &= -1.0 \cdot 10^{12}\\
  a_1 &= 8.33 \cdot 10^{9}\\
  a_2 &= 7.50 \cdot 10^{10}\\
  a_4 &= 4.167 \cdot 10^{9}  \\
  a_5 &= 3.33 \cdot 10^{10}\\
  a_8 &= 4.167 \cdot 10^{10}\\
  a_{10} &= 4.167 \cdot 10^{9}
\end{align*}
Or simplify the fraction: divide both numerator and denominator by
$10^{450}$:
\[
 P_{N_3}(P_X(t)) = \frac{1.098848191 \cdot 10^{146}}
     {\left(-1000 + 8.33  t + 75.0  t^2 + 4.167 t^4 + 33.3  t^5
        + 41.67 t^8 + 4.167 t^{10}\right)^{50}}
\]
Or rewrite and simplify further, taking the $50$th root:
\[ P_{N_3}(P_X(t)) = \left( \frac{A}{Q(t)} \right)^{50} \]
where
\[ \frac{A}{Q(t)} = \frac{0.1615055828 \cdot 10^{3}}
     {-1000 + 8.33  t + 75.0  t^2 + 4.167 t^4 + 33.3  t^5
        + 41.67 t^8 + 4.167 t^{10}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think it is better to attach the output such that readers can easily judge  your answer (whether voting it up or whatever...) without having to compiling the code by themselves.