# How can I position \twocolumn bottom of the page

Tags: two-column

On the following example, long equation shows up on the top of the second page.

The equation example is taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/321805/127048.

```tex
\documentclass[5p,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\section{Start}
Hello World
\twocolumn[
{
    \begin{equation}\begin{split}
f_{r:n}(x)&=\frac{n!}{(r-1)!\,(n-r+1)!}
   \Biggl[ \biggl( \frac{x-1}{k}  \biggr)^{\!r-1}
           \biggl( \frac{k-x+1}{k}\biggr)^{\!n-r+1} \\
  &\qquad -\biggl( \frac{x}{k}    \biggr)^{\!r-1}
           \biggl( \frac{k-x}{k}  \biggr)^{\!n-r+1} \,
   \Biggr]+ f_{r-1:n}(x)
\end{split}\end{equation}
       }\bigskip]
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

Is it possible to force the long equation to show up at the bottom of the first page or right after the `Hello World` text? Please note that I want to show the long equation in both of the two columns rather than fitting it into single column of the double-column.

Comment: The `\twocolumn` command forces a page break. If you don't want to force a page break, don't execute `\twocolumn`. Do please tell us what you *are* trying to achieve.

Comment: @MadyYuvi - By loading the `elsarticle` document class with the option `5p`, the document is already in two-column mode. That's why it's rather puzzling for the OP to use `\twocolumn`, and it's why I asked the OP to state what it is that they are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Mico Sorry, I am not aware that the option `5p` meant that `twocolumn` mode, I gave just a general suggestion about `multicols`... Please excuse... I'll remove my comment...

Comment: @Mico In a doublecolumn paper, I want to show a long equation to take place in both two columns rather than fitting it into single column in a double-column paper. I tried to trick latex using `\twocolumn[{ ... }]` to show the equation in the full wide page but it only puts the equation top of the page rather than bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the package `cuted` to [Micos`s](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/653890/161015) answer, the wide equation can be put after "Hello world".

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[5p,%times % don't specify the 'times' option
]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'aligned' environment
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % for a more up to date Times Roman math font

\usepackage{cuted}% strip environment

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    
    \section{Start}
    
    \noindent
    Hello world.
    
    \begin{strip}
    \begin{equation} % see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/321805/5001
        \begin{aligned}[b]
            f_{r:n}(x)
            &=\binom{n}{r-1} %\frac{n!}{(r-1)!\,(n-r+1)!}
            \biggl[ \biggl( \frac{x-1}{k}  \biggr)^{\!r-1}
            \biggl( \frac{k-x+1}{k}\biggr)^{\!n-r+1} \\
            &\quad  -\biggl( \frac{x}{k}    \biggr)^{\!r-1}
            \biggl( \frac{k-x}{k}  \biggr)^{\!n-r+1} \,
            \biggr ] + f_{r-1:n}(x)
        \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
    \bigskip
    
    \begin{equation}
        f_{r:n}(x)  =\binom{n}{r-1} %\frac{n!}{(r-1)!\,(n-r+1)!}
        \biggl[ \biggl( \frac{x-1}{k}  \biggr)^{\!r-1}
        \biggl( \frac{k-x+1}{k}\biggr)^{\!n-r+1} -\biggl( \frac{x}{k}    \biggr)^{\!r-1}
        \biggl( \frac{k-x}{k}  \biggr)^{\!n-r+1} \,
        \biggr ] + f_{r-1:n}(x)
    \end{equation}

    \end{strip}
    
    \noindent
    Hello other world.
    \begin{multline} % see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/321863/5001
        f_{r:n}(x)
        =\binom{n}{r-1} %\frac{n!}{(r-1)!\,(n-r+1)!}
        \biggl[ \biggl( \frac{x-1}{k}  \biggr)^{\!r-1}
        \biggl( \frac{k-x+1}{k}\biggr)^{\!n-r+1} \\
        -\biggl( \frac{x}{k}    \biggr)^{\!r-1}
        \biggl( \frac{k-x}{k}  \biggr)^{\!n-r+1} \,
        \biggr ] + f_{r-1:n}(x)
    \end{multline}

    \lipsum[1-7]
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You asked,

> Is it possible to force the long equation to show up ... right after the Hello World text?

Short answer: Yes.

Longer answer: Simply omit the `\twocolumn[{...}\bigskip]` "wrapper". Since you employ the [elsarticle](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle) document class with the option `5p`, the document is already in two-column mode. It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve by issuing the `\twocolumn` directive to begin with -- except, probably involuntarily, force an unnecessary and unwanted page break while also, likely quite unexpectedly, switching to single-column mode.

While on the subject of the `elsarticle` document class: If at all possible, don't use the `times` document class option, as it loads the borderline obsolete `txfonts` package. Instead, do yourself a favor and load the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages explicitly, as is done in the code shown below.

The following screenshot shows two approaches -- one with the help of an `equation/aligned` combination, the other with a `multline` environment -- to making the long equation fit inside the fairly narrow column. The results of both approaches are fine; which one you may prefer is mainly a matter of tast (about which there is no arguing, right?).

[image]

```
\documentclass[5p,%times % don't specify the 'times' option
              ]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'aligned' environment
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % for a more up to date Times Roman math font

\begin{document}

\section{Start}

\noindent
Hello world.
\begin{equation} % see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/321805/5001
\begin{aligned}[b]
f_{r:n}(x)
  &=\binom{n}{r-1} %\frac{n!}{(r-1)!\,(n-r+1)!}
   \biggl[ \biggl( \frac{x-1}{k}  \biggr)^{\!r-1}
           \biggl( \frac{k-x+1}{k}\biggr)^{\!n-r+1} \\
  &\quad  -\biggl( \frac{x}{k}    \biggr)^{\!r-1}
           \biggl( \frac{k-x}{k}  \biggr)^{\!n-r+1} \,
   \biggr ] + f_{r-1:n}(x)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\noindent
Hello world.
\begin{multline} % see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/321863/5001
f_{r:n}(x)
  =\binom{n}{r-1} %\frac{n!}{(r-1)!\,(n-r+1)!}
   \biggl[ \biggl( \frac{x-1}{k}  \biggr)^{\!r-1}
           \biggl( \frac{k-x+1}{k}\biggr)^{\!n-r+1} \\
          -\biggl( \frac{x}{k}    \biggr)^{\!r-1}
           \biggl( \frac{k-x}{k}  \biggr)^{\!n-r+1} \,
   \biggr ] + f_{r-1:n}(x)
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not work as I wanted. I want long equation to show up in bot of the two columns rather than fitting into single column

Comment: @alper - My apologies for not understanding your phrase "force the long equation to show up ... right after the `Hello World` text".

Comment: my apologies I was not able to explain my question clearly :-(