# How can I separate an equation over two or three lines?

Tags: equations

I am having the following equation as below

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:36}
\emph{$SINR^{D,UL}_{k,n}$} =  \frac{p_{k,n} |h_{k,n}|^2}{\sum_{m=1}^{M} \omega_{n,m}p_{m,n}|h^{C}_{m,n}|^2   + \sum_{c^{'}=1}^{C^{'}} \sum_{m^{'}}^{M^{'}} \omega^{'}_{n,m^{'},c^{'}}p_{m^{'},n}|h^{C}_{m^{'},n,k,c^{'}}|^2   + \sum_{c^{'}=1}^{C^{'}} \sum_{k^{'}}^{K^{'}} \zeta^{'}_{n,k^{'},c^{'}}p_{k^{'},n}|h^{D}_{k^{'},n,k,c^{'}}|^2  + N_{0}B}  
\end{equation}
```

The equation does not very well fit on one line. How can I separate this over two or three lines? Please see my figure example.

Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: Check out this page:
[How can I split an equation over two lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/how-can-i-split-an-equation-over-two-lines?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps use `multline`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\abs[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
  \label{eq:36}
  \mathrm{SINR}^{D,UL}_{k,n} =  p_{k,n} \abs{h_{k,n}}^2
  \biggl(
  \sum_{m=1}^{M} \omega_{n,m} p_{m,n} \abs{h^{C}_{m,n}}^2 \\
  + \sum_{c'=1}^{C'} \sum_{m'}^{M'} \omega'_{n,m',c'} p_{m',n} \abs{h^{C}_{m',n,k,c'}}^2 \\
  + \sum_{c'=1}^{C'} \sum_{k'}^{K'} \zeta'_{n,k',c'} p_{k',n} \abs{h^{D}_{k',n,k,c'}}^2
  + N_{0}B
  \biggr)^{\!-1}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or introduce aliases:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\abs[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:36}
  \mathrm{SINR}^{D,UL}_{k,n} =  \frac{p_{k,n} \abs{h_{k,n}}^2}{X + Y + Z + N_{0}B}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align*}
  X &= \sum_{m=1}^{M} \omega_{n,m} p_{m,n} \abs{h^{C}_{m,n}}^2 \\
  Y &= \sum_{c'=1}^{C'} \sum_{m'}^{M'} \omega'_{n,m',c'} p_{m',n} \abs{h^{C}_{m',n,k,c'}}^2 \\
  Z &= \sum_{c'=1}^{C'} \sum_{k'}^{K'} \zeta'_{n,k',c'} p_{k',n} \abs{h^{D}_{k',n,k,c'}}^2
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also make that nasty thing you showed in the question, but I do not recommend that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\abs[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:36}
  \mathrm{SINR}^{D,UL}_{k,n} =  \frac{p_{k,n} \abs{h_{k,n}}^2}{
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \sum_{m=1}^{M} \omega_{n,m} p_{m,n} \abs{h^{C}_{m,n}}^2 + {} \\
      \sum_{c'=1}^{C'} \sum_{m'}^{M'} \omega'_{n,m',c'} p_{m',n} \abs{h^{C}_{m',n,k,c'}}^2 + {} \\
      \sum_{c'=1}^{C'} \sum_{k'}^{K'} \zeta'_{n,k',c'} p_{k',n} \abs{h^{D}_{k',n,k,c'}}^2 + N_{0}B
    \end{pmatrix}
  }
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! I like the last one example as you suggested.

Thanks a lot to @Henri Menke

Comment: Mmmhh… :-(  `\substack` is meant for super/subscripts, and for this reason it typesets its argument in `\scriptstyle`; note that this entails that you get no space around binary operators and relation symbols.  What about a `pmatrix` environment, instead?  It usesn`\textstyle`, which seems much more appropriate…  Also, I guess you didn’t notice the `^{'}` idiom that the OP uses repeatedly, `|...|` instead of `\lvert ... \rvert`, or better, `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`…

Comment: @user3727281 Why are you picking the garbage solution when I presented two other perfectly reasonable ones?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti You are right.  I didn't put too much effort into it.  Using `pmatrix` instead of `\substack` is a good.  I wouldn't say a substack is completely wrong here because somehow you need to cramp all that stuff in the denominator but then this part is ugly anyway and cannot be made looking decent.