# My row vector runs off the page in an `align*` environment

Tags: math-mode, formatting, align

I am trying to format a row vector with fifty columns such that it remains on a single page (perhaps over multiples lines). The vector is in an `align*` environment. My code is shown below

```
\begin{align*}
 \mathbf{y^*}&=\left(x_1,\dots,x_{50}\right) \\
 &=\left(7, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 7, 8, 40, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 11, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 9, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1 \right)
\end{align*}
```

How can this be formatted such that the vector does not run off the page.

**Edit**

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace} % for "\setstretch" macro
\newcommand\mybox[1]{\parbox[t]{0.75\textwidth}{
\setstretch{1.33}\raggedright$\displaystyle #1$}}
 
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{y^*}&=(x_1,\dots,x_{50}) \\
&=\mybox{(7, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 7, 8, 40, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 11, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 9, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
2, 0, 1)}
\end{align*}
```

**Another idea**

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\mathbf{x^*}=&\left(x_1,\dots,x_{50}\right) \\
=&(7, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 7, 8, 40, 1, \\ & 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, \\ 
 & 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 11, 0, 1, 0, \\ & 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 9, 1, \\ & 0, 
 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1)
 \end{split}
 \end{equation*}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410942/10898

Comment: @azetina I tried to follow their method. I used the packages in the example and altered my column vector to `\mybox{(7, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 7, 8, 40, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 11, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 9, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1)}`. However, the vector still runs off the page.

Comment: Can you update your question so that we can see how you implemented the technique?

Comment: @azetina I have done so.

Comment: Maybe tedious, but putting the data in a sub array would be easier in this case.

Comment: Try this: \documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\begin{document} 
\begin{align*}
 \mathbf{y^*} &=\left(x_1,\dots,x_{50}\right) \\
     &=
     \begin{array}[t]{@{}r@{}*{9}{@{\ }c<{,}}@{\ }c@{}l}
     (& 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1,&  \\
      & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1\phantom{,}&)  \\
     \end{array}
\end{align*}
\end{document}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of ideas

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[75]
\begin{multline*}
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{y^*}
 &= (x_1,\dots,x_{50}) \\
 &= (7, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 7, 8, 40, 1,
\end{aligned}
\\
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 11, 0, 1, 0,
\\
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 9, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1)
\end{multline*}
\lipsum*[75]
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{y^*}
& = (x_1,\dots,x_{50}) \\
&= \begin{aligned}[t]
   (& 7, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 7, 8, 40, 1, \\
    & 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, \\
    & 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 11, 0, 1, 0, \\
    & 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 9, 1,\\
    & 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1)
   \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\lipsum*[75]
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{y^*}
&= (x_1,\dots,x_{50}) \\
&= (
\begin{array}[t]{@{\:}c*{9}{@{\;,\;}c}}
7 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 7 & 8 & 40 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 11 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 9 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \rlap{$\:)$}
\end{array}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried using the `\equation*` environment (I have placed the code in my post). Though, I don't like the look of it. It would look better if the first entries in subsequent rows vertically aligned with the first entry of the first row.

Comment: @MB I've added an alternative.

Comment: This is perfect. Obviously I can ignore the `lipsum*[4]` and only take that within the `align*` environment, right?

Comment: @MB Of course, the `\lipsum` is just for the dummy text. I have added yet another version.

Answer (score 4):

With use of the package `\linegoal`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{linegoal}

\begin{document}
    \[
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{y^*}
    & = (x_1,\dots,x_{50}) \\
    & = \parbox[t]{0.8\linegoal}{
        (7, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 7, 8, 40, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
         1, 1, 11, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 9, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 
         0, 1)
         }
\end{aligned}
    \]
\end{document}
```

For final result need to be compiled twice:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)