# Left align and right align in the same equations block

Tags: equations

I have two really long equations that don't fit into one line. I would like to display them as

```
first_eq LHS, super super super super long =
                                        first_eq RHS, aligned right, also not short
second_eq LHS, not as long as first eq = 
             second_eq RHS, aligned right, pretty loooooooooooooooooooooooooong too
```

**Note that all lines are aligned to a side, either left or right.**
How can I achieve this within latex? I'm somewhat familiar with `align`, so if I wouldn't have to learn new packages that'd be great, but not a deal breaker.

I'm not sure whether the two equation signs should be vertically aligned, that *could* potentially look neat.

Neither of the solutions in the closed-as question work here. For example,

```
\begin{multline}
(\rho + \delta  + (1-\beta)f(m(a, \bar u, l))J(a, \bar u, l) = \\
\left((1 - \beta)(p(a, \bar u, l) - b) + dJ(a, \bar u, l)\mathbf z(a, \bar u, l)\right)\\
\rho U (a, \bar u, l) = \\
b + f(m(a, \bar u, l))\frac{\beta}{1-\beta}J(m(a, \bar u, l))  + \eta \underbar U + dU(a, \bar u, l)\mathbf z(a, \bar u, l) \\
 \perp \underbar U \leq U(a, \bar u, l) \leq \bar U(a, \bar u, l)
\end{multline}
```

does not align them as I want to but equations rather hover weirdly in the center. Wrapping it around in `dmath` has no impact whatsoever.

Comment: @Tiuri: the environment is `multline`, not `multiline`

Comment: @Tiuri: You can delete and re-post the correct version, so we can delete the superfluous comments.

Comment: You probably want to use `multline` from the `amsmath` package, see for example here: [How can I split an equation over two (or more) lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/how-can-i-split-an-equation-over-two-or-more-lines)

Comment: @Tiuri I've now mentioned in the question why that's no solution.

Comment: @FooBar: Well, in your original example, there were only two equations with two lines each, and it was not obvious that there is need to have them in the same environment. In case two `multline`s after each other are not an option for you, you can manually force left- and right-alignment inside `multline` with the `\shoveleft` and `\shoveright` macros. I voted for reopen to add that as a solution.

Comment: @FooBar: Did you want the equations numbered?

Comment: @Werner Both options would be nice-to-have, but by default no.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `multlined` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\begin{multlined}[c][\dimexpr\textwidth-4em]
\shoveleft{
(\rho + \delta  + (1-\beta)f(m(a, \bar u, l))J(a, \bar u, l) =\hfill} \\
\bigl((1 - \beta)(p(a, \bar u, l) - b) + dJ(a, \bar u, l)\mathbf z(a, \bar u, l)\bigr)
\end{multlined}
\\
\begin{multlined}[c][\dimexpr\textwidth-4em]
\shoveleft{\rho U (a, \bar u, l) =\hfill} \\
b + f(m(a, \bar u, l))\frac{\beta}{1-\beta}J(m(a, \bar u, l))  + \eta \underbar U + dU(a, \bar u, l)\mathbf z(a, \bar u, l) \\
 \perp \underbar U \leq U(a, \bar u, l) \leq \bar U(a, \bar u, l)
\end{multlined}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

written as two `multlined` equations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\begin{multlined}[\linewidth]
(\rho + \delta  + (1-\beta)f(m(a, \bar u, l))J(a, \bar u, l) = \\
\mbox{}\hfill\left((1 - \beta)(p(a, \bar u, l) - b) + dJ(a, \bar u, l)\mathbf z(a, \bar u, l)\right)
\end{multlined}\\
 %
\begin{multlined}[\linewidth]
\rho U (a, \bar u, l) = \\
b + f(m(a, \bar u, l))\frac{\beta}{1-\beta}J(m(a, \bar u, l))  + \eta \underbar U + dU(a, \bar u, l)\mathbf z(a, \bar u, l) \\
 \perp \underbar U \leq U(a, \bar u, l) \leq \bar U(a, \bar u, l)
\end{multlined}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: i can't test, but if i could, i would try nesting the two `multlined` equations within `gather`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, thank you for tip, i consider it in edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

In `amsmath`'s `multline` environment, one can force a specific line to be left- or right-aligned by invoking the `\shoveleft` or `\shoveright` macros:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
(\rho + \delta  + (1-\beta)f(m(a, \bar u, l))J(a, \bar u, l) = \\
\shoveright{\left((1 - \beta)(p(a, \bar u, l) - b) + dJ(a, \bar u, l)\mathbf z(a, \bar u, l)\right)} \\
\shoveleft{\rho U (a, \bar u, l)} = \\
b + f(m(a, \bar u, l))\frac{\beta}{1-\beta}J(m(a, \bar u, l))  + \eta \underbar U + dU(a, \bar u, l)\mathbf z(a, \bar u, l) \\
\perp \underbar U \leq U(a, \bar u, l) \leq \bar U(a, \bar u, l)
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]