# Break equation without amsmath

Tags: equations

The equation is too long to fit in the page. Is it possible to break it without using package amsmath? Does anyone know how to solve this ;

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\title{FEM assignment} 
\author{El & Cauist}
 \date 
\begin{document}
 \maketitle \ 
\begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
 -(\textbf{\tilde{\nabla}_1}-\textbf{\tilde{\nabla}_0})^T[r\t‌​extbf{D}(\textbf{\ti‌​lde{\nabla}_1}+\text‌​bf{\tilde{\nabla}_0}‌​)\textbf{u}]=r \textbf{b} \end{equation}
```

Comment: Related: [Can't get packages to work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412895/5764)

Comment: You should be a bit more specific. There's [How can I split an equation over two (or more) lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3782/5764)...

Comment: Please show us the equation in question. Incidentally, could you tell us why you don't want to use the `amsmath` package?

Comment: Of course, there is a archaic `\begin{eqnarray}` ... `\end{eqnarray}` environment. (I almost do not dare to say it loud, but this has even some advantages, e.g. it works with `\pause` from the beamer package. But it also has disadvantages.)

Comment: I cant seem to get packages to work in my programme...
Here is the code so far:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\title{FEM assignment}
\author{El & Cauist}
\date

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\

\begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
    -(\textbf{\tilde{\nabla}_1}-\textbf{\tilde{\nabla}_0})^T[r\textbf{D}(\textbf{\tilde{\nabla}_1}+\textbf{\tilde{\nabla}_0})\textbf{u}]=r \textbf{b}
\end{equation}

Comment: Did you try `\author{El \& Cauist} ` instead of `\author{El & Cauist} `?

Comment: Use also `\date{}`. Do not use  `\textbf{}` in math mode.

Comment: I want to use amsmath, but it doesn't work. I get a lot of errors, for example complaing about using \tilde

Comment: the problem with `\tilde` is that it requires math mode, and you are using it within `\textbf` which resets the node to text mode.  if you use `\mathbf` instead, there should be no error reported.

Answer (score 3):

There are several serious issues with your code. The equation being too long to fit on a single line, let alone on a single page, is *not* one of them.

- Don't use `\textbf` in math mode. Use either `\mathbf` or `\bm`; the latter requires loading the `bm` package.
- The code you've posted is infested with various invisible unicode-encoded characters. Get rid of them!
- Optional: Consider using `\widetilde` instead of `\tilde`.
- `&` is a "special" character in TeX and LaTeX. If you need to typeset an ampersand, don't write `&`; instead, write `\&`.

Again, I have no idea why you claim that the equation is so long that it won't fit on a page.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm} % for "\bm" macro
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
-(\tilde{\bm{\nabla}}_1-\tilde{\bm{\nabla}}_0)^T
[r\mathbf{D}(\tilde{\bm{\nabla}}_1+ \tilde{\bm{\nabla}}_0)\mathbf{u}]
 = r \mathbf{b} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: 3rd item shows the same code on `\tilde`.