# How to fit a large equation that goes out of the page?

Tags: equations

I have the following equation

```
\begin{equation}
    Ep = (Required Personality Level of Each Resource - Assigned Personality 
    Level of each Resources) \times (da\textsubscript{i})
\end{equation}
```

but it is too large as is.
How should I write it so it can fit nicely on the page?

Comment: Is the hyphen between “Resource” and “Assigned” meant to be a minus sign?

Comment: See also: [math mode - How can I split an equation over two (or more) lines - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/how-can-i-split-an-equation-over-two-or-more-lines)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Mathematical symbols where created to represent the meaning of longer descriptive words in a short form for easy inclusion in complex formulas with possible repetition. I would choose a suitable symbol/character to represent that long sentence like this (choose your own descriptive symbol):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  Ep = P_l \times da_i,
\end{equation}
%
where $P_l =$ Required Personality Level of Each Resource-Assigned Personality Level of all Resources

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: I would go a step further, and say "where $P_l$ is the required personality ...", explaining in words what the symbol is.  There's no gain to using math here.

Answer (score 12):

break your long text into two lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    Ep = \left(\begin{tabular}{l}
                Required Personality Level of Each Resource-\\
                Assigned Personality Level of each Resources
                \end{tabular}\right)
        \times (da_{i})
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: no other option is available?

Comment: what option? you can't store elephant into suitcase ... or do you like to make equation invisible small?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are looking for autobreak option in display math? If yes, refer the below tag:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{autobreak}

\begin{document}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{align}
\begin{autobreak}
    Ep = 
(Required Personality Level of Each Resource - Assigned Personality 
    Level of each Resources) 
\times (da\textsubscript{i})
\end{autobreak}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `amsmath` I can think of two more options: you can use

- `multiline` (justified multiline formula)
- `split` (allows to align about certain character without bulky `tabular` construction)

environments. Note that text in math equations is typically upright; I also adapted subscript notation to use in math environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
    Ep = (\text{Required Personality Level of Each Resource}\\
    - \text{Assigned Personality Level of each Resources}) \\
    \times (da_\mathrm{i})
\end{multline}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        Ep &= (\text{Required Personality Level of Each Resource}\\
        &- \text{Assigned Personality Level of each Resources}) \\
        &\times (da_\mathrm{i})
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your equation does not fit on a single line, then the `multline` environment probably is what you need:

```
\begin{multline}
    first part of the equation \\
    = second part of the equation
\end{multline}
```

If you also need some alignment respect to the first part, you can use `split`:

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        first part &= second part #1 \\
        &= second part #2
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Both environments require the `amsmath` package.

See also `aligned` as pointed out [in an answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51116894/311834).