# List of equation aligned on the left and which return to the line

Tags: equations, alignment

I am trying to write different equations aligned on the left (that's ok) and which go back to the line after the `=` sign. Also, I do not want any numeration of the equation: that's why there is a `*`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
4 &= 2 + 2\\\nonumber
A &= B + C + D + E + F + G + H + I + J + K + L + M + N + O + P + Q + R + S + T + U + W + X + Y + Z  \\\nonumber
6 &= 3 + 3&&
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

As you can imagine the long equation will not fit in one line. The problem is that in my case it continues even after the end of the page and I do not see the end. As you can see:

[image]

Does someone know how to force it to go to the line, after the `=` sign of the previous line ?

Comment: it makes it a lot easier for people to see the issue if you provide a complete small document. In particular show how big your page is. Also why do you have `&&` at the end of each row?  you can just linebreak with `\\ ` and use a `\quad` space to indent the wrapped line, or use a nested `aligned` environment or several other alternatives (you don't need `\nonumber` in a starred environment.

Comment: Done, I have changed the equation and shown an image to better explain the problem. @DavidCarlisle

Comment: Related: [How can I split an equation over two (or more) lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3782/5764)

Comment: well you didn't do the main thing i suggested which is to provide a test document (see the code in Bernard's answer which is a complete document, so you can test it without guessing needed packages and page size)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have had all the packages I use.

Comment: No!!!! that is worse!  Put yourself in the position of someone wanting to help. That person needs a _small_ (so with no packages not needed for the question) but _complete_ document (so they can take the code run it through latex and see or debug the problem and test answers. So all you needed to do was add `\documentclass` load amsmath, and add `\begin{document}..\end{document} but perhaps you might have added `[twocolumn]` or `[a4paper]`  which change the text width so change where any suggested line breaks should be.

Comment: Three comments about your preamble. (1) The `hyperref` package should be loaded last. (2) The `subfigure` package is deprecated and shouldn't be used any longer. Since you're using the `caption` package, I suggest you load the `subcaption` package instead of the `subfigure` package. (3) The `amsfonts` package is loaded automatically by the `amssymb` package -- no need to load `amsfonts` separately.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But that's a whole book... so it's quite complicated to just extract the proper packages. I have no idea what most do... Do you want me to remove this part ?

Comment: @Mico Ok, I did (1), (2) and (3) ! It's working. Thanks for the additional help !

Comment: No I meant literally add 4 extra lines. I'll do it this time:

Comment: See as it is now (a) anyone can copy the code and see the issue and (b) they know a target width for line wrapping. If you wanted two column a4 add `[a4paper,twocolumn]` and then the width would be much less and possibly the answers would suggest a different layout, and (c) by generating the image from exactly the posted code, you avoid typos (which you did not have, but I _always_ have if I type untested tex fragments....)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks a lot ! I was just afraid to suppress a package which could cause some mysterious problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it one of these you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtoolsh}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
4 &= 2 + 2&&\\
A &= \begin{multlined}[t]B + C + D + E + F + G + H + I + J + K+ L \\+ M + N + O + P + Q + R + S + T + U + W
\end{multlined} \\
6 &= 3 + 3 
\end{flalign*}
\vskip1cm

 \begin{flalign*}
4 &= 2 + 2&&\\
A &=B + C + D + E + F + G + H + I + J + K+ L \\
  & + M + N + O + P + Q + R + S + T + U + W \\
6 &= 3 + 3
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes !! That would be that. But is it compulsary to import the new packages ? @Bernard

Comment: It works perfectly. But could I aligned the `+ M + N + O + P + Q + R + S + T + U + W` to the `=` ont the left? Right now it's aligned on the right. @Bernard

Comment: @AgapeGal'lo: Your original request didn't make it explicit, but it seemed like you were after an 
automated breaking of the equation. Is this the case?

Comment: @AgapeGal'lo: I've added another solution.

Comment: @Bernard Perfect: Both of you solutions work perfectly!! Thank you, and sorry, may be my question wasn't asked well.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that uses a `\parbox` for the material to the right of the `=` symbol in the 2nd equation. An advantage of this approach is that it allows automatic line breaking.

[image]

The macro `\mybox` takes two arguments: the first, optional, argument gives the width of the box (`0.9\textwidth` by default); the second, mandatory, argument gives the material to be placed (in displaystyle math mode) in the "box". If you wanted to make the box occupy, say, a width of `0.93\textwidth`, you'd simply write `\mybox[0.93]{B + C + ... + Z}`.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
% default width of parbox = 0.9\textwidth
\newcommand\mybox[2][0.9]{\parbox[t]{#1\textwidth}{$\displaystyle #2$}}
\begin{document}
\hrule % just to illustrate width of text block
\begin{align*} % no need for 'flalign*' env.
4 &= 2 + 2\\
A &= \mybox{B + C + D + E + F + G + H + I + J + K + L + M + 
            N + O + P + Q + R + S + T + U + W + X + Y + Z}\\
6 &= 3 + 3
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the `fleqn` option to amsmath to left align all your equations automatically. Also, I would align the `+` sign after the `=` sign above using the `align*` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
4 &= 2 + 2\\
A &= B + C + D + E + F + G + H + I + J + K+ L \\
  &\phantom{{}=} + M + N + O + P + Q + R + S + T + U + W \\
6 &= 3 + 3
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

> [image]