# I get many errors from the following beamer code:

Tags: beamer, errors

I keep getting errors from this code, can someone help me figure out the problem?

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Set Up to NGM with an Infinitely-lived Consumer}
To solve the NGM model, consider an infinitely lived consumer 
with an additively separable utility function that satisfies:
\begin{equation}
max_{\lbrace C_{t},L_{t},K_{t+1}\rbrace_{t=0}^{\infty}}
\sum_{t=1977}^{\infty} = \beta^{t-1977}
\lbrack \gamma log C_{t}+(1-\gamma ) log(N_{t} \overline{h}-L_{t})\rbrack \\ 
\text{s.t. (for all  t=0,1,...):} \\ 
C_{t}+L_{t+1}-K_{t} = w_{t} L_{t} + (r_{t}-\delta)K_{t} \\ 
K_{1977}=\overline{K_{1977}} 
\end{equation} 
\end{frame}
```

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Could you please make your code compilable? (See also: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228))

Comment: You seem to try to break a long eqution over multiple lines. The following might be interesting: [How can I split an equation over two (or more) lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3782/134144)

Comment: You might also want to use `\log` and `\max` instead of `log` and `max`.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your code is that you're employing an `equation` environment to typeset several lines of displayed math material. I suggest you use a `gather*` environment rather than an `equation` environment.

The exposition of the consumer's utility function and of the constrained maximization problem also leave a lot to be desired. For instance, the condition `K_{1977}=\overline{K}_{1977}` is a starting or initial condition and need not -- in fact, *should not* -- be repeated for `t=0,1,\dots`. And, the `=` symbol in the middle of `\sum_{t=1977}^{\infty} = \beta^{t-1977}` cannot possibly be correct.

The following modified exposition may be more easily accessible by readers:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{NGM with an infinitely-lived consumer}

To solve the NGM model, consider an infinitely lived consumer
with an additively separable period utility function given by:
\[
\gamma \log C_{t}+(1-\gamma ) \log(N_{t} \bar{h}-L_{t})\,.
\]
Utility maximization is performed jointly over $C_t$, $L_t$, and $K_{t+1}$, $t=0,1,\dots$:
\begin{gather*}
\max_{\lbrace C_{t},L_{t},K_{t+1}\rbrace_{t=1977}^{\infty}}\quad
\sum_{t=1977}^{\infty} \beta^{t-1977}
\bigl[ \gamma \log C_{t}+(1-\gamma ) \log(N_{t} \bar{h}-L_{t})\bigr] \\
\intertext{such that $K_{1977}=\overline{K}_{1977}$ and, for all $t=0,1,...$}
C_{t}+L_{t+1}-K_{t} = w_{t} L_{t} + (r_{t}-\delta)K_{t} \,.
\end{gather*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!