# Two columns: automatic new line with compound words and inside equations

Tags: equations, line-breaking, two-column, hyphenation

The two-column design works fine, but I encountered three problems:

1. Every time I use a word that already has a hyphen (`-`) in it, LaTeX stops breaking the word with new hyphens to make it fit the column (so the word reaches into the next column).
2. Every time I use `$$` in a sentence, it can mess up by reaching out of the column as well
3. Equations (`\begin{equation}`) doesn't break automatically either

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{cryptocode}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn
\pagebreak

\section{Diffie-Hellman-Schlüsselaustausch}
\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{equation}
{\displaystyle \mathrm {i} \hbar {\frac {\partial }{\partial t}}\psi (\mathbf {r} ,t)=\left(-{\frac {\hbar ^{2}}{2m}}\Delta +V(\mathbf {r} ,t)\right)\psi (\mathbf {r} ,t)},
\end{equation}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
F = \{F_{x} \in  F_{c} : (|S| > |C|) \cap 
(minPixels  < |S| < maxPixels) \cap 
(|S_{connected}| > |S| - \epsilon)
\}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.stackexchange! Better to include a Minimum Working Example (MWE) so people can have a "feel" of the problem you are experiencing. It is also very likely that the problem could be easily traced if you provide the MWE.

Comment: About the section title,  you can use  some like `\section{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{Diffie-Hellman-Schlüsse\-laustausch}}`  About the equation, I think that is a [duplicate of this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/how-can-i-split-an-equation-over-two-or-more-lines).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, some general points about your document setup:

- No need to load `amsfonts` explicitly, as it's loaded automatically by `amssymb`.
- Instead of

  ```
  \usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
  ```

  do just write

  ```
  \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
  ```

  unless you're a fan of code clutter.
- Unless you must adhere to an explicit requirement to employ pre-1995 German spelling and hyphenation rules, do replace

  ```
  \usepackage[german]{babel}
  ```

  with

  ```
  \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % note the 'n' in 'ngerman'
  ```

---

Next, you may not be aware of the fact that LaTeX and TeX do *not* line-break words if they are parts of compound hyphenated words. Thus, "Schlüsselaustausch" doesn't get hyphenated and line-broken if it occurs in the [to me atrocious-looking!] "Diffie-Hellman-Schlüsselaustausch" string. I suggest you add the instructions

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\raggedright}
```

to the preamble. This will force LaTeX to insert a line break immediately before "Schlüsselaustausch". Adding these two instructions is probably a good idea anyway, given that (a) your document is typeset in two-column mode and (b) hyphenation of words in sectioning headers is often frowned upon as running against "fine typography". I don't personally share the view that one should never hyphenate words in a sectioning header, but I'm aware that quite a few people do hold this view. When in doubt, it's better not to get involved in a debate with them...

---

I'm not sure I know how to interpret your sentence that "Every time I use `$$` in a sentence, it can mess up by reaching out of the column as well". For sure, `$$` is used in PlainTeX (not so much in LaTeX) to initiate and terminate display-math mode. If, instead, you're referring to inline-math mode, i.e., if you meant to write `$...$`, the simple rule is that TeX can insert line breaks at *some*, fairly restrictive locations inside an inline formula, but *not at arbitrary locations*.

Since you didn't provide an example of an inline math formula which you need to get line-broken, it's not possible to give more specific advice on how to proceed. A general piece of advice, though: do keep all inline-math expressions short and simple. You readers will appreciate the gesture, and you'll run into far fewer pesky line-breaking issues.

---

About line-breaking in `equation` environments: I'm not sure what the basis may be for your view that LaTeX performs (or should perform?) line-breaking on the material in such environments. In fact, the opposite is the case. Hence, if you want line breaks in a long displayed equation, you have to supply them yourself, *and* you have to use a display math environment other than `equation`. (Well, there *is* a package called `breqn` that can perform automatic line-breaking. However, its results often require further, manual tweaking.)

For the equation at hand, I suggest you employ a `multline` environment (provided by the `amsmath` package) and supply two break points (indicated by `\\`). For the formula at hand, inserting breakpoints immediately before the `\cap` directives looks like a sensible way to proceed. To help the reader's eye "parse" the equation quickly, you may also apply some manual sizing of the curly braces and round parentheses; see the screenshot below for a case that uses `\Bigl`/`\Bigr` as well as `\bigl`/`\bigr`.

Two additional comments while on the subject of math typesetting. First, you seem to have a fondness for encasing subformulas in curly braces. The extra curly braces achieve *nothing* but create code clutter. Do try to wean yourself off this habit. Second, if entire natural-language words appear in a formula, encase them in either `\mathrm` or `mathit` statements; otherwise, LaTeX will process these words as if they're formulas in their own right -- frequently with undesirable outcomes. For the second equation, this concerns the words "minPixels", "maxPixels", and "connected".

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed unless your TeX distribution is quite old
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%%\usepackage{amsfonts} %% not needed
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % ngerman, not german, right?
\usepackage{cryptocode}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\raggedright}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn
%%\pagebreak % unnecessary

\section{Diffie-Hellman-Schlüsselaustausch}

\dots
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{i} \hbar \frac{\partial }{\partial t} \psi(\mathbf{r},t) =
\biggl( -\frac{\hbar ^{2}}{2m} \Delta 
+V(\mathbf{r},t) \biggr) \psi(\mathbf{r},t) \,,
\end{equation}
\dots
\begin{multline} 
F = \Bigl\{ F_{x} \in  F_{c} : \bigl( |S| > |C| \bigr) \\
  \cap \bigl( \mathrm{minPixels}  < |S| < \mathrm{maxPixels} \bigr) \\
  \cap \bigl( |S_{\mathrm{connected}}| > |S| - \epsilon \bigr) \Bigr\}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. But your solution only helps me for all sections - but not for the plain text?

Comment: @KlaraM.Lund - I wrote earlier, "LaTeX and TeX do not line-break words if they are parts of compound hyphenated words"; an example of such a work is, of course, `Diffie-Hellman-Schlüsselaustausch`. The `babel` package, when loaded with the `ngerman` option, provides the following work-around: replace `-` with  `"=`. E.g., if you replace `Diffie-Hellman-Schlüsselaustausch` with `Diffie-Hellman"=Schlüsselaustausch`, LaTeX will be able to hyphenate `Schlüsselaustausch` as needed. (I wouldn't permit hyphenation of the proper names "Diffie" and "Hellman"; hence, do keep the first instance of `-`.)