# Long numbered equation in align

Tags: equations, align

I am using for now the following code to produce two equations, that should each be numbered and aligned. However, both equations are too long, so they should be on two lines.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    \frac{\partial x_{t,i}}{\partial t} &= \alpha(x_{t,i-1}-2x_{t,i}+x_{t,i+1})-
    \beta(x_{t,i-2}-4x_{t,i-1}+6x_{t,i}-4x_{t,i+1}+x_{t,i+2})\\
    &+ f_{x}(x_{t,i},y_{t,i})\\
    &= -\beta x_{t,i-2}+(\alpha+4\beta)x_{i-1,t}+
    (-2\alpha-6\beta)+x_{i,t} + (\alpha+4\beta)x_{i+1,t})\\
    &-\beta x_{t,i+2} + f_{x}(x_{t,i},y_{t,i})
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

The result is this:
[image]

But I want both equation to get a number, and that the second line of each equation is more to the middle instead of under the =-sign as I did. I tried the multline, but that does not allow me to align, inserting \ gives me equation numbers for each line (so four in total), so if someone has an idea, that would be great!

Comment: There are many questions on this site regarding multiline equations. Please have a look at them, for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/how-can-i-split-an-equation-over-two-or-more-lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `align` environment with `\nonumber`, which suppresses labeling for specified rows:

```
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial x_{t,i}}{\partial t} &=&& \alpha(x_{t,i-1}-2x_{t,i}+x_{t,i+1})-
\beta(x_{t,i-2}-4x_{t,i-1}+6x_{t,i}-4x_{t,i+1}+x_{t,i+2}) \nonumber\\
&&&+ f_{x}(x_{t,i},y_{t,i})\\ 
&=&& -\beta x_{t,i-2}+(\alpha+4\beta)x_{i-1,t}+
(-2\alpha-6\beta)+x_{i,t} + (\alpha+4\beta)x_{i+1,t}) \nonumber\\
&&&-\beta x_{t,i+2} + f_{x}(x_{t,i},y_{t,i})
\end{align}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Since this is a multiline display, because it has two numbered items, you need `align` and can nest `split` inside it.

I moved the “`f_x`” term at the beginning to get better breaks: the “alpha” and “beta” terms cannot be squeezed in one line, unless you have a very wide text block.

Note that I smashed the bottom of the fraction so not to push down the second part of the first equation.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\smash[b]{\frac{\partial x_{t,i}}{\partial t}}
  &= f_{x}(x_{t,i},y_{t,i}) + \alpha(x_{t,i-1}-2x_{t,i}+x_{t,i+1}) \\
  &\qquad - \beta(x_{t,i-2}-4x_{t,i-1}+6x_{t,i}-4x_{t,i+1}+x_{t,i+2})
\end{split}
\\[1ex]
\begin{split}
  &=f_{x}(x_{t,i},y_{t,i}) -\beta x_{t,i-2}+(\alpha+4\beta)x_{i-1,t} \\
  &\qquad+(-2\alpha-6\beta)+x_{i,t} + (\alpha+4\beta)x_{i+1,t})-\beta x_{t,i+2}
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]