# How do I split only a part of an equation on multiple lines?

Tags: spacing, alignment

I would like to have an equation for an equivalence where the left-hand side is centered and the right-hand side is spaced over multiple lines. Researching this so far only lead me to the answer on how to split up a regular equation in general.

[How can I split an equation over two (or more) lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/how-can-i-split-an-equation-over-two-or-more-lines)

what I am looking for is something like this

[image: only right-hand side is stretched over to lines]

or with curly brackets that span two lines like so

[image]

How could I do this? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first problem, I suggest you employ an `alignedat` environment; for the second, I suggest you employ a `cases` environment. Both environments are provided by the `amsmath` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\coloneqq' macro and access to the 'amsmath' package
\begin{document}
\[
x\in G \quad \iff \quad
\begin{alignedat}{2}
&g_i(x)\le0 \quad &&\text{ for } i\in I \coloneqq \{1,\dots,m\},\\
&h_j(x)=0   \quad &&\text{ for } j\in J \coloneqq \{1,\dots,p\}.
\end{alignedat}
\]

\[
\mathbf{1}_A(x) \coloneqq 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $x\in A$,} \\
0 & \text{if $x\notin A$.}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sir @Mico; for equations and its alignment, hope you are one of a king...Great...

Comment: @MadyYuvi - Thanks! - I'm blushing... :-)