# Problem using alignat with 2 &&'s

Tags: align

I am having trouble aligning the second block in my example below...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}\nonumber
    \frac{\partial U^\varepsilon_{p,q}}{\partial x_3} &= \frac{i\omega\Gamma_1(\kappa_1) m(x_3/\varepsilon^2)}{\varepsilon}\bigg(pU^\varepsilon_{p,q} - qU^\varepsilon_{p,q}\bigg) \\ \nonumber
    &+\frac{i\omega\Gamma_2(\kappa_1) m(x_3/\varepsilon^2)}{2\varepsilon}e^{2i\omega\bar\zeta(\kappa_1)x_3/\varepsilon}&&\bigg(pU^\varepsilon_{p+1,q}e^{ih\bar\zeta(\kappa_1)x_3 - i\omega\bar{c}_{66}\kappa_1\lambda x_3/(\bar{c}_{44}\bar{\zeta}(\kappa_1))} \\ \nonumber
    &\phantom{+} &&-qU^\varepsilon_{p,q-1}e^{-ih\bar\zeta(\kappa_1)x_3 + i\omega\bar{c}_{66}\kappa_1\lambda x_3/(\bar{c}_{44}\bar{\zeta}(\kappa_1))}\bigg) \\ \nonumber
    &+\frac{i\omega\Gamma_2(\kappa_1) m(x_3/\varepsilon^2)}{2\varepsilon}e^{-2i\omega\bar\zeta(\kappa_1)x_3/\varepsilon}&&\bigg(pU^\varepsilon_{p-1,q}e^{-ih\bar{\zeta}x_3 + i\omega\bar{c}_{66}\kappa_1\lambda x_3/(\bar{c}_{44}\bar{\zeta}(\kappa_1))} \\
    &\phantom{+} &&-qU^\varepsilon_{p,q+1}e^{ih\bar{\zeta}(\kappa_1)x_3 - i\omega\bar{c}_{66}\kappa_1\lambda x_3/(\bar{c}_{44}\bar{\zeta}(\kappa_1))}\bigg) 
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

The second line where \bigg(p appears should not have a large space between there and the exponential previous to it, could someone lend me a piece of advice please? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You're using the wrong method. See [math mode - How can I split an equation over two (or more) lines - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/how-can-i-split-an-equation-over-two-or-more-lines)

Answer (score 2):

You might add a negative space in the first row to make TeX think it's shorter.

There will still be a small gap, due to the minus sign in the exponent, but I feel that alignment is more important.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
\frac{\partial U^\varepsilon_{p,q}}{\partial x_3}
&= \frac{i\omega\Gamma_1(\kappa_1) m(x_3/\varepsilon^2)}{\varepsilon}
   \bigl(pU^\varepsilon_{p,q} - qU^\varepsilon_{p,q}\bigr) \hspace{-5em}
\nonumber \\
&+ \frac{i\omega\Gamma_2(\kappa_1) m(x_3/\varepsilon^2)}{2\varepsilon}
   e^{2i\omega\bar\zeta(\kappa_1)x_3/\varepsilon}
   &&\Bigl(pU^\varepsilon_{p+1,q}e^{ih\bar\zeta(\kappa_1)x_3 -
     i\omega\bar{c}_{66}\kappa_1\lambda x_3/(\bar{c}_{44}\bar{\zeta}(\kappa_1))}
\nonumber \\
&  &&-qU^\varepsilon_{p,q-1}e^{-ih\bar\zeta(\kappa_1)x_3 +
     i\omega\bar{c}_{66}\kappa_1\lambda x_3/(\bar{c}_{44}\bar{\zeta}(\kappa_1))}\Bigr)
\nonumber \\
&+ \frac{i\omega\Gamma_2(\kappa_1) m(x_3/\varepsilon^2)}{2\varepsilon}
   e^{-2i\omega\bar\zeta(\kappa_1)x_3/\varepsilon}
   &&\Bigl(pU^\varepsilon_{p-1,q}e^{-ih\bar{\zeta}x_3 +
     i\omega\bar{c}_{66}\kappa_1\lambda x_3/(\bar{c}_{44}\bar{\zeta}(\kappa_1))}
\nonumber \\
&  &&-qU^\varepsilon_{p,q+1}e^{ih\bar{\zeta}(\kappa_1)x_3 -
     i\omega\bar{c}_{66}\kappa_1\lambda x_3/(\bar{c}_{44}\bar{\zeta}(\kappa_1))}\Bigr)
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

Note the usage of `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` for two reasons:

1. `\bigg` is too big;
2. one should set the delimiters to opening and closing atoms.

In the first line `\bigl` and `\bigr` seems more than enough.

I used `geometry` because, according to your picture, you have a larger text width than the default.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I propose this layout based on `\multlined` nested in `aligned`, using smaller parentheses, and the `geometry` package, to have more decent margins:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
    \frac{\partial U^\varepsilon_{p,q}}{\partial x_3} &=\frac{i\omega\Gamma_1(\kappa_1) m(x_3/\varepsilon^2)}{\varepsilon}\mathrlap{\Bigl(pU^\varepsilon_{p,q} - qU^\varepsilon_{p,q}\Bigr)} \\
    &\begin{multlined} + \frac{i\omega\Gamma_2(\kappa_1) m(x_3/\varepsilon^2)}{2\varepsilon}e^{2i\omega\bar\zeta(\kappa_1)x_3/\varepsilon}\Bigl(pU^\varepsilon_{p+1,q}e^{ih\bar\zeta(\kappa_1)x_3 - i\omega\bar{c}_{66}\kappa_1\lambda x_3/(\bar{c}_{44}\bar{\zeta}(\kappa_1))} \\[-1.5ex]
   -qU^\varepsilon_{p,q-1}e^{-ih\bar\zeta(\kappa_1)x_3 + i\omega\bar{c}_{66}\kappa_1\lambda x_3/(\bar{c}_{44}\bar{\zeta}(\kappa_1))}\Bigr)
    \end{multlined}\\
    &\begin{multlined}[b] + \frac{i\omega\Gamma_2(\kappa_1) m(x_3/\varepsilon^2)}{2\varepsilon}e^{-2i\omega\bar\zeta(\kappa_1)x_3/\varepsilon}\Bigl(pU^\varepsilon_{p-1,q}e^{-ih\bar{\zeta}x_3 + i\omega\bar{c}_{66}\kappa_1\lambda x_3/(\bar{c}_{44}\bar{\zeta}(\kappa_1))} \\[-1.5ex]
    -qU^\varepsilon_{p,q+1}e^{ih\bar{\zeta}(\kappa_1)x_3 - i\omega\bar{c}_{66}\kappa_1\lambda x_3/(\bar{c}_{44}\bar{\zeta}(\kappa_1))}\Bigr)
    \end{multlined}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]