# How can I carry over my equation?

Tags: equations

I just write the long equation and it is wider than the page, so LaTex doesn't carry over on the next line and i need it to do somehow.For example,how can I do it with my long equation:

```
\begin{equation}
 min J = P(0)m_0^2+P(0) \cdot D_0^x+P(1)\cdot R_1(0)+P(2)\cdot R_1(1)+P(3)R_1(2)+ 
    \Gamma (0) L^T(0)\cdot(B^T(0)\cdotP(1)B(0)+Q)\cdot L(0)+ 
    \Gamma (1) L^T(1)\cdot(B^T(1)\cdot P(2)B(1)+Q(1))\cdot L(1)+
    \Gamma (2) L^T(2)\cdot(B^T(2)\cdotP(3)B(2)+Q(2))\cdot L(2) 
\end{equation}
```

The `\newline` cmd and `\\` don't work

Comment: Related: [How can I split an equation over two (or more) lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3782/134144)

Comment: multiline doesn't work correctly either

Comment: multline works correctly if it is used as intended, if you don't show how you are using it or what output you got, it is hard to help

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My thoughts exactly, Overleaf recommends it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I propose this solution with `aligned` (without any ampersand, it is right-aligned). I took the liberty to replace Q in the second line with Q(0) (I thought you had mistyped it, but maybe I'm wrong). Also, I think the final `+` look better at the beginning of the following line

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned} \min J =P(0)m_0^2+P(0) \cdot D_0^x+P(1)\cdot R_1(0)+P(2)\cdot R_1(1)+P(3)R_1(2) \\
   {} + \Gamma (0) L^T(0)\cdot\bigl(B^T(0)\cdot P(1)B(0)+Q(0)\bigr)\cdot L(0) \\
   {} + \Gamma (1) L^T(1)\cdot\bigl(B^T(1)\cdot P(2)B(1)+Q(1)\bigr)\cdot L(1) \\
   {} + \Gamma (2) L^T(2)\cdot\bigl(B^T(2)\cdot P(3)B(2)+Q(2)\bigr)\cdot L(2)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! @Bernard, why compiler says "undefined control sequence"? I use amsmath package...Don't get it

Comment: @Programmer1988:  I have no such message. Can you see from the .log file what the ‘undefined control sequence’ is?

Comment: it's my fault, I typed \cdotP instead of \cdot P

Comment: Thanks a lot, i accepted your answer

Answer (score 4):

You may use the `IEEEeqnarray` environment from the `IEEEtrantools` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}
 \min J &=& P(0)m_0^2+P(0) \cdot D_0^x+P(1)\cdot R_1(0)+P(2)\cdot R_1(1)+P(3)R_1(2)\\
       & & \negmedspace {}+\Gamma (0) L^T(0)\cdot(B^T(0)\cdot P(1)B(0)+Q)\cdot L(0)\\
       & & \negmedspace {}+\Gamma (1) L^T(1)\cdot(B^T(1)\cdot P(2)B(1)+Q(1))\cdot L(1)\\
       & & \negmedspace {}+\Gamma (2) L^T(2)\cdot(B^T(2)\cdot P(3)B(2)+Q(2))\cdot L(2)\IEEEyesnumber\\
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Black line shows page margin.

Comment: it is not the array, you're wrong

Comment: @Programmer1988 Sorry, I didn't understand your comment. What is "not the array"?

Comment: @Programmer1988 ieeeeqnarray os an improved version of the standard eqnarray and is a viable alternative to the amsmath alignments. Your first comment here is wrong.

Comment: +1. I would also replace `min J` with `\min J`.

Answer (score 2):

If conserving (vertical) space is important to you, you could place the equation in a `\parbox` directive and employ `\linebreak` directives where needed.

Oh, and I would get rid of the `\cdot` "crutches". If making the long expression easily parsable is an objective, I can suggest replacing the "outer" round parentheses in lines 2 to 4 with square brackets.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\min J = \parbox[t]{0.75\textwidth}{$
P(0)m_0^2+P(0)D_0^x + P(1)R_1(0) + P(2)R_1(1) + P(3)R_1(2)+ 
    \linebreak\Gamma(0) L^T(0)[B^T(0) P(1)B(0)+Q(0)] L(0)+ 
    \linebreak\Gamma(1) L^T(1)[B^T(1) P(2)B(1)+Q(1)] L(1)+
    \linebreak\Gamma(2) L^T(2)[B^T(2) P(3)B(2)+Q(2)] L(2)$}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Bernard - Thanks for the edit!

Comment: You're welcome. You're not not the only one to have typos – some days I have almost as many  as pips in a mandarin!