# Half of my lstlisting is not shown in latex

Tags: equations, listings

I have used a big equation in latex. Half of my code is not shown in latex. Here is my equation:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{equation}\label{HammingTappering}
        AF = \exp^{-j\dfrac{N-1}{2} \Psi} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} [0.54-0.46\cos(\frac{2n\pi}{N-1})\times \exp^{jn\psi}] = \exp^{-j\dfrac{N-1}{2} \Psi}\times ( \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} [0.54\times \exp^{jn\psi}] + \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} [-0.46\cos(\frac{2n\pi}{N-1})\times \exp^{jn\psi}]) = \exp^{-j\dfrac{N-1}{2} \Psi}\times (0.54\times \exp^{j\dfrac{N-1}{2} \Psi}\times \dfrac{\exp^{j\dfrac{N}{2} \Psi} - exp^{-j\dfrac{N}{2} \Psi}}{\exp^{j\dfrac{\Psi}{2}} - exp^{-j\dfrac{\Psi}{2} }}  + \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} [-0.23\times [\exp^{j\dfrac{2n\pi}{N-1}} + \exp^{-j\dfrac{2n\pi}{N-1}}]\times \exp^{jn\psi}]) = \exp^{-j\dfrac{N-1}{2} \Psi}\times (0.54\times \exp^{j\dfrac{N-1}{2} \Psi}\times \dfrac{\sin(\dfrac{N}{2}\psi)}{\sin(\dfrac{\psi}{2})}  + \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} [-0.23\times [\exp^{j\dfrac{2n\pi}{N-1}} + \exp^{-j\dfrac{2n\pi}{N-1}}]\times \exp^{jn\psi}]) = \exp^{-j\dfrac{N-1}{2} \Psi}\times (0.54\times \exp^{j\dfrac{N-1}{2} \Psi}\times \dfrac{\sin(\dfrac{N}{2}\psi)}{\sin(\dfrac{\psi}{2})}  +  [-0.23\times [\exp^{j(\dfrac{2\pi}{N-1}+\psi)\dfrac{N-1}{2}}\times \dfrac{\sin((\dfrac{2\pi}{N-1}+\psi)\dfrac{N}{2})}{\sin((\dfrac{2\pi}{N-1}+\psi))} + \exp^{j(\dfrac{-2\pi}{N-1}+\psi)\dfrac{N-1}{2}}\times \dfrac{\sin((\dfrac{-2\pi}{N-1}+\psi)\dfrac{N}{2})}{\sin((\dfrac{-2\pi}{N-1}+\psi))}]])=0.54\times \dfrac{\sin(\dfrac{N}{2}\psi)}{\sin(\dfrac{\psi}{2})}  +  [0.23\times [ \dfrac{\sin((\dfrac{2\pi}{N-1}+\psi)\dfrac{N}{2})}{\sin((\dfrac{\pi}{N-1}+\dfrac{\psi}{2}))} +  \dfrac{\sin((\dfrac{-2\pi}{N-1}+\psi)\dfrac{N}{2})}{\sin((\dfrac{-\pi}{N-1}+\dfrac{\psi}{2}))}]]
        \eqref{HammingTappering}
    \end{equation}
\end{center}
```

The result would be like this:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Refer to [math mode - How can I split an equation over two (or more) lines - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/how-can-i-split-an-equation-over-two-or-more-lines) (and linked questions if needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[ left=0.5in,
top=0.6in,
right=1.0in,
bottom=0.8in,
headsep=0.25in,
a4paper]
{geometry}

\begin{document}
     \begin{equation}\label{HammingTappering}
     \begin{aligned}
        AF & = \exp^{-j\dfrac{N-1}{2} \Psi} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} [0.54-0.46\cos(\frac{2n\pi}{N-1})\times \exp^{jn\psi}]\\
           &= \exp^{-j\dfrac{N-1}{2} \Psi}\times ( \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} [0.54\times \exp^{jn\psi}] + \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} [-0.46\cos(\frac{2n\pi}{N-1})\times \exp^{jn\psi}]) \\
           &= \exp^{-j\dfrac{N-1}{2} \Psi}\times (0.54\times \exp^{j\dfrac{N-1}{2} \Psi}\times \dfrac{\exp^{j\dfrac{N}{2} \Psi} - \exp^{-j\dfrac{N}{2} \Psi}}{\exp^{j\dfrac{\Psi}{2}} - \exp^{-j\dfrac{\Psi}{2} }}  + \\
           &\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} [-0.23\times [\exp^{j\dfrac{2n\pi}{N-1}} + \exp^{-j\dfrac{2n\pi}{N-1}}]\times \exp^{jn\psi}])\\
           &= \exp^{-j\dfrac{N-1}{2} \Psi}\times (0.54\times \exp^{j\dfrac{N-1}{2} \Psi}\times \dfrac{\sin(\dfrac{N}{2}\psi)}{\sin(\dfrac{\psi}{2})}  +\\
           &\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} [-0.23\times [\exp^{j\dfrac{2n\pi}{N-1}} + \exp^{-j\dfrac{2n\pi}{N-1}}]\times \exp^{jn\psi}]) \\
           &= \exp^{-j\dfrac{N-1}{2} \Psi}\times (0.54\times \exp^{j\dfrac{N-1}{2} \Psi}\times \dfrac{\sin(\dfrac{N}{2}\psi)}{\sin(\dfrac{\psi}{2})}  \\
           &+  [-0.23\times [\exp^{j(\dfrac{2\pi}{N-1}+\psi)\dfrac{N-1}{2}}\times \dfrac{\sin((\dfrac{2\pi}{N-1}+\psi)\dfrac{N}{2})}{\sin((\dfrac{2\pi}{N-1}+\psi))} + \exp^{j(\dfrac{-2\pi}{N-1}+\psi)\dfrac{N-1}{2}}\times \dfrac{\sin((\dfrac{-2\pi}{N-1}+\psi)\dfrac{N}{2})}{\sin((\dfrac{-2\pi}{N-1}+\psi))}]])\\
           &=0.54\times \dfrac{\sin(\dfrac{N}{2}\psi)}{\sin(\dfrac{\psi}{2})}  +  [0.23\times [ \dfrac{\sin((\dfrac{2\pi}{N-1}+\psi)\dfrac{N}{2})}{\sin((\dfrac{\pi}{N-1}+\dfrac{\psi}{2}))} +  \dfrac{\sin((\dfrac{-2\pi}{N-1}+\psi)\dfrac{N}{2})}{\sin((\dfrac{-\pi}{N-1}+\dfrac{\psi}{2}))}]]
        \eqref{HammingTappering}
        \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]